# How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?

Tags: java, macos

How can you change the default version of Java on a mac?

Comment: what does executing `/usr/libexec/java_home` tell you?

Comment: /usr/libexec/java_home returns /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Could be you just need to reboot. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yep restarted the computer and the terminal... no change.

Comment: Could you please accept the highly voted answer from @markhellewell below? It would have helped me find it a bit faster, and it's just nice. :)

Comment: @Venkat It's now almost 7 years since the question, did any of the answers solve the problem? ;) As Taytay mentioned, would be nice to have an accepted answer for such a popular question.

Comment: Agreed.  Please (try to) accept an answer.  This still shows up as a "unanswered question" in SOF queries.

Comment: For those wanting /usr/libexec/java_home to be managed by SDKMAN see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76523554/328275

Answer (score 2451):

First run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` which will output something like the following:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
1.8.0_05, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Pick the version you want to be the default (`1.6.0_65-b14-462` for arguments sake) then:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0_65-b14-462`
```

or you can specify just the major version, like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Now when you run `java -version` you will see:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Add the `export JAVA_HOME…` line to your shell’s init file.

For Bash (as stated by [antonyh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132325/antonyh)):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

For Fish (as stated by ormurin)

```
set -x JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -d64 -v1.8)
```

Updating the .zshrc file should work:

```
nano ~/.zshrc

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0)
```

Press CTRL+X to exit the editor
Press Y to save your changes

```
source ~/.zshrc
echo $JAVA_HOME
java -version
```

Comment: @MattO'Brien it’s something which depends on the shell you’re using, and the configuration you have in place, so I can’t give a complete solution for that…

Comment: those really are backticks the `export` line

Comment: This did not work for me. Grab the path from running java_home -V and add this to the export command, like this export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"

Comment: @oden it does work as long as your “java_home” executable isn’t broken.  Also, as pointed out, the backticks are  required (they are replaced by the result of the expression contained within them)

Comment: This works in Bash - `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` - also note, java_home allows partial matches so you don't have to include the full version as it'll find the latest installed. This makes updates easier.

Comment: Make sure you are using ` ` not ' ' for export.

Comment: With proper setup, the response from `java_home` decides which `java` command gets executed. However, since `java_home` doesn't depend on `JAVA_HOME`, setting it will not change anything about the response from `java -version`. If you have in mind *some* mechanism which connects `JAVA_HOME` with the `java` command, your answer does not mention it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I can’t tell if you are trolling.  It is *most certainly* possible to tell the `java` command which version of Java you want to run by setting JAVA_HOME.  The key thing here is that JAVA_HOME is being set by the output of the `java_home -v …` command.  Backticks replace the shell command contained within them with the result of that command.  Consider the following:

    JAVA_HOME=`java_home -v 1.8`

becomes, after evaluation

    JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java1.8/home

Comment: Hm, I stand corrected. `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/java` does honor `JAVA_HOME`, if present. If not, or if invalid, it relies on a direct call to `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

Comment: As a note to the future reader, this mechanism works only if you have installed Apple's Java before installing Oracle's, and that seems to be an ever less common case.

Comment: OS X yosemite only shows 1.6, even though 1.8.45 is installed.

Comment: Another option is to uninstall the java version you don't want (if its default) :)

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

is giving:

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_121-zulu-8.20.0.5, x86_64: "Zulu 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_121, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_121)`
In this case, won’t help much, because it appears to select the first that starts with 1.8.0_121 ??
Any ideas how to handle this case?

Comment: 2018 and still this works but only for the current running shell, for system-wide setting please see the answer below or https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169445/5237164

Comment: I wish I could upvote this every time I have to google "os x switch java version" and get back here

Comment: Doesn't work. I ran the exact same steps and I still see jdk 8 instead of `9.0.1`.

Comment: this isn't working for me anymore. it fixes just JAVA_HOME but maven or other programs are still using my other java version. combined with this solution, i came to a new idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885494/how-can-i-change-mac-oss-default-java-vm-returned-from-usr-libexec-java-home/55763491#55763491

Comment: Just an enhancement for this:
add this fun to bash_profle `function jc() {export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)}`....
Then, 
invoke from terminal:
jc 1.8 or
jc 12.0.1
this will change the java version

Comment: If you are using a fish terminal then you can use the following command:
`set -x JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -d64 -v1.8)`
or better yet add it to your .config/fish/config.fish file

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. However, I have to do it every time I restart my terminal. Any suggestion on how to make the change permanent?

Comment: @Julian you can put the export line in your .bash_profile or .bashrc

Comment: Where does $JAVA_HOME comes from ? overall the answer works, but I don't get what it does. When this variable is set what happens? I suspect that when java process is starting it checks for this variable, and if it is present, it starts the java with the appropriate version, am I righ ?

Comment: This work for me, i change from java 11 to java 8 in a downgrade...

Comment: Couldn't find any other solution but this worked like a charm, thanks! :D

Comment: What do you do when `java -version` lists a version that is not listed with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`? It confuses me a lot.

Comment: This is the best answer, using jenv or sdkman adds just unnecessary magic, which breaks sooner or later.

Comment: This does not seem to work for Java 8 (OpenJDK) on macOS 12.1. I have created a separate question, specifically for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557354/unable-to-create-z-shell-alias-to-activate-java-8-openjdk-on-macos

Comment: Does not answer the question how to select the Java version for macOS.

Comment: In case you have issues setting it up on nano, for a Java 17 version on mac we should take out the parenthesis, then run the source command.
Do type this line to update the .zshrc file:

```export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.9/Contents/Home```

Answer (score 585):

This answer is an attempt to address: how to **control java version system-wide** (not just in currently running shell) when **several versions of JDK** are installed for development purposes on **macOS El Capitan or newer (Sierra, High Sierra, Mojave)**. As far as I can tell, none of the current answers do that (*).

As a developer, I use several JDKs, and I want to switch from one to the other easily. Usually I have the latest stable one for general use, and others for tests. But I don't want the system (e.g. when I start my IDE) to use the latest "early access" version I have for now. I want to control system's default, and that should be latest stable.

The following approach works with **Java 7 to 12** at least (early access at the time of this writing), with **Oracle JDK** or **OpenJDK** (including [builds by AdoptOpenJDK produced after mid-October 2018](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2018/10/macos-binary-changes)).

#### Solution without 3rd party tools:

- leave all JDKs at their default location, under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. The system will pick the highest version by default.
- **To exclude a JDK from being picked by default, rename its `Contents/Info.plist` to `Info.plist.disabled`**. That JDK can still be used when `$JAVA_HOME` points to it, or explicitly referenced in a script or configuration. It will simply be ignored by system's `java` command.

System launcher will use the JDK with highest version among those that have an `Info.plist` file.

When working in a shell with alternate JDK, pick your method among existing answers (`jenv`, or custom aliases/scripts around `/usr/libexec/java_home`, etc).

---

Details of investigation [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/hogmoru/8e02cf826c840914a8ed93fd418ed88e).

---

(*) Current answers are either obsolete (no longer valid for macOS El Capitan or Sierra), or only address a single JDK, or do not address the system-wide aspect. Many explain how to change `$JAVA_HOME`, but this only affects the current shell and what is launched from there. It won't affect an application started from OS launcher (unless you change the right file and logout/login, which is tedious). Same for jenv, it's cool and all, but as far as I can tell it merely changes environment variables, so it has the same limitation.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, since `jenv` nor `JAVA_HOME` are able to set the system-wide java version, i.e. the one Eclipse would use.

Comment: I've renamed "Info.plist" to "Info.plist.disabled" yet my java control panel is still picking up the latest java version installed on my machine. Does anyone know if this is still working? As of july/2017 with Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, as mentioned in "Details of investigation" (linked above): "Installing a JDK also overwrites `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/`. Apparently this is the one that the new Preferences pane will launch -- this is the only exception I found to my solution: that thingy will still use JDK9 (latest I installed), but no other Java application does."

Comment: @HuguesM. I'm on Sierra and I've been trying to get a legacy application to use Apple's JDK 6 when I launch it (the application requires Java 6). I tried renaming Info.plist, but still when I launched an application it seemed to hang as usual (ever since the upgrade to Sierra). The only other JDK installed is 7.

Comment: Worth noting that java versions are found in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines, and that the above excellent working solution is within that context.

Comment: Thanks 'control java version system-wide' is what I was looking into

Comment: Exactly, this is the best and the most functional solution for this question. Unfortunately so.

Comment: I wrote a script to make this proces even easier using your method!
https://github.com/JoniVR/JavaVersionSwitcher

Comment: Does not work. It changes the version of java invoked on the command line, but when I try to run Eclipse, it points to the old version and generates this error:"The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this answer. This fixed launching applications from the OS launcher.

Comment: this is the *CORRECT* answer.

Comment: working with `dcevm-11.0.1` and `openjdk-11.0.1.jdk` installed at the same time

Comment: I did vote up this answer, but I have come to realize this does not work (at least not on macOS 10.14.2). Renaming Info.plist to Info.plist.disabled resulted in Java 11 to no longer be the default version of Java. This was desired, however, Java 11 then was no longer available at all as a filterable Java version using java_home -v.

Comment: Even you set the JAVA_HOME like `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` , you need to do this because, you do not know how some java apps are looking for the java home. Very helpful post.

Comment: please mark as the answer this is it, systemwide! Some applications for whatever reason only use this as the JDK and there is no way to change it in the application--changing this system wide setting works

Comment: Note, there is a downside to mv'ing the Info.plist files aside - the java_home tool will no longer acknowledge that they exist, as that is the configuration file it reads.

Comment: When using `jenv`, consider `jenv enable-plugin export` which will set up `JAVA_HOME` based on jenv settings.  You do need to restart your shell the first time.

Comment: This worked for me too, as I was trying to get Ghidra to use JDK11 but it kept using JDK16 and having compatibility issues. One way I found to _validate_ that a given JDK was effectively disabled (after renaming `Info.plist`) was to open a shell, run `unset JAVA_HOME`, and then run `java -version`. This way `java` will have to pick a JDK, just like Ghidra or any other UI-based app would do (as opposed to launched from a terminal). Before renaming anything it would say 16.0, and when I renamed `Info.plist` in JDK16 it stopped using it by default.

Thanks for this post!

Comment: Works for me on Ventura for OpenJDK 19.  Thanks!

Comment: Does not work with actual eclipse 2023-09 on MacOS Ventura 13.6.2. eclipse will not start with this version set in "eclipse.ini".

Answer (score 421):

Adding to the above answers, I put the following lines in my `.bash_profile` (or `.zshrc` for MacOS 10.15+) which makes it really convenient to switch (including @elektromin's comment for java 9):

```bash
alias j20="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 20`; java -version"
alias j19="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 19`; java -version"
alias j18="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 18`; java -version"
alias j17="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`; java -version"
alias j16="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 16`; java -version"
alias j15="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 15`; java -version"
alias j14="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14`; java -version"
alias j13="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 13`; java -version"
alias j12="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12`; java -version"
alias j11="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`; java -version"
alias j10="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 10`; java -version"
alias j9="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9`; java -version"
alias j8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`; java -version"
alias j7="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`; java -version"
```

After inserting, execute `$ source .bash_profile`

I can switch to Java 8 by typing the following:

```
$ j8
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This is the syntax for Java 9:

```alias j9="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9`; java -version"```

Comment: Using ``alias j10="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`; java -version"`` and then typing `j10` allows you to switch back to the current version of Java (in my case Java 10)

Comment: I would make a cli tool similar to `nvm` for switching Java versions, but the acronym `jvm` already means something else :)

Comment: I get this error when sourcing:  `/Users/me/.zshrc:8: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: @cosbor11 for `.zshrc` use `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12)`

Comment: add j8 after this declaration line, so that every time it default it to Java8. If required execute j11 to change version.

Comment: Be aware that when running `sudo java -version` the version will be different than running as your user..

Comment: this is just genius! helped a lot!

Answer (score 67):

***Due to multiple Homebrew, cast(Deprecation Notice [AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk)), and MacOS updates I'm posting this updated answer.***

Homebrew tap [AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk) is officially deprecated in favor of the [temurin](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/temurin) casks provided directly from the Homebrew project but Homebrew is the best way to manage and work with different Java versions.

***In case you already have Homebrew and [AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk) cast installed, please untap this brew tap first:***

```
$ brew untap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
```

if you do not have Homebrew installed.

**1 - Install Homebrew.**

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**2 - To download the latest Jave version (16):**

```
$ brew install --cask temurin
```

**3 - To install other versions:**

```
$ brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
$ brew install --cask temurin8
$ brew install --cask temurin11
$ brew install --cask temurin17
$ brew install --cask temurin18
$ brew install --cask temurin19
$ brew install --cask temurin21
```

**4 - Switch between different versions of Java**

Switching between different versions of Java, you only need to add the following to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`.

In this case, we want to be able to switch between Java8, Java11, Java17... and Java21:

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
export JAVA_17_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v17)
export JAVA_18_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v18)
export JAVA_19_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v19)
export JAVA_21_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v21)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'
alias java17='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_17_HOME'
alias java18='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_18_HOME'
alias java19='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_19_HOME'
alias java21='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_21_HOME'

# default to Java 21
java21
```

**5 - Reload `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` for the aliases to take effect:**

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

**6 - Finally you can use the aliases to switch between different Java versions.**

```
$ java8
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
```

***Old Guide if you have old Homebrew and MacOS versions...***

I will share my experiences with macOS Big Sur v11.4, the best way to deal with these problems is by installing Java using Homebrew:

**1 - Install Homebrew.**

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**2 - Install Homebrew Cask.**

```
$ brew tap homebrew/cask-versions 
$ brew update 
$ brew tap homebrew/cask
```

**3 - Install the latest version of Java**

```
$ brew cask install java
```

**4 - Install the other needed versions of Java (Java8, Java11, Java13).**

```
$ brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk

$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk13
$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk14
```

**5 - Switch between different versions of Java**

Switching between different versions of Java, you only need to add the following to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`.

In this case, we want to be able to switch between Java8, Java11, Java13 and Java14:

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
export JAVA_13_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v13)
export JAVA_14_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v14)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'
alias java13='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_13_HOME'
alias java14='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_14_HOME'

# default to Java 14
java14
```

**6 - Reload `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` for the aliases to take effect:**

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

**7 - Finally you can use the aliases to switch between different Java versions.**

```
$ java8
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
```

For more info, you can see this post: [How to Use Brew to Install Java on Mac](https://devqa.io/brew-install-java/)

Comment: Mind making a minor edit @hermeslm? Seeing this: ```brew tap caskroom/cask
Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.```

Comment: Good catch @hafichuk, this worked at the moment of this answer. I will edit it, thanks.

Comment: @hermeslm `brew cask install` won't work with newer versions, add an update of: `brew install cask packageName`. ReferenceL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413621/homebrew-cask-option-not-recognized

Comment: I had to run `brew install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` instead of `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: Nov 2022 update for Mac: 

`export JAVA_11_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.16.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_17_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.4.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_18_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.2.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'
alias java17='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_17_HOME'
alias java18='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_18_HOME'

# default to Java 14
java18`

Comment: For those that would like some feedback use e.g.

`alias java17='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_17_HOME && echo JAVA_HOME set to $JAVA_HOME'`

Answer (score 66):

A small fish function based on /usr/libexec/java_home

```
function jhome
    set JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home $argv)
    echo "JAVA_HOME:" $JAVA_HOME
    echo "java -version:"
    java -version
end
```

If you don't use fish, you can do something similar in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

jhome () {
  export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home $@`
  echo "JAVA_HOME:" $JAVA_HOME
  echo "java -version:"
  java -version
}
```

Then to switch between javas do:

```
$> jhome           #switches to latest java
$> jhome -v 1.7    #switches to java 1.7
$> jhome -v 1.6    #switches to java 1.6
```

ref: https://gist.github.com/kenglxn/1843d552dff4d4233271

Comment: this only changes for the specific terminal session.  Is there a way to update this to change it system wide?

Comment: I had to write `export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home $argv)` instead of the second line of your `jhome` function.

Answer (score 53):

Use [jenv](https://github.com/jenv/jenv) is an easy way. (Update 2022)

1. Install jenv: see [Getting started](https://github.com/jenv/jenv#1-getting-started)
2. Install java with brew

   ```
   brew install openjdk@11
   ln -s /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk

   #other java
   brew install openjdk@8
   brew install openjdk@17
   ```
3. Add java to jenv

   ```
   jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```
4. Use: refer to [jenv](https://www.jenv.be)

Comment: Clean and nice solution.

Comment: Instead of "jenv use java 1.8", I had to use "jenv shell 1.8".  "shell" could also be "global" or "local" depending on the need.

Comment: jenv is nice when it works. Would recommend against it though, as it doesn't "really" change the default java version used, evident by running the command "/usr/libexec/java_home -V", only the JAVA_HOME. This causes weird  problems with some applications, e.g. Eclipse.

Comment: Besides that paranoidal part of me suggests against curling anything to bash. Even if you __think__ the site is trusted no-one can **guarantee** you it's un-hackable. Use your OS' package manager.

Comment: That info is outdated. Check [official documentation](http://www.jenv.be/) or [more detailed instructions](https://developer.bring.com/blog/configuring-jenv-the-right-way/).

Comment: Configuring `jenv` is different now. Please refer to this - https://www.jenv.be/

Answer (score 42):

install JDK, not just JRE

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```

gives

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
```

next

```
touch .bash_profile

open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile
```

TextEdit will show you a blank page which you can fill in.

add to doc: 
    `export   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home`

in terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
```

try the command:

`javac -version`

should output:

```
javac 1.8.0_111
```

Comment: upvote for showing how to install JDK as well

Answer (score 41):

It is a little bit tricky, but try to follow the steps described in [Installing Java on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks). Basically, you gonna have to update your alias to `java`.

Step by step:

After installing JDK 1.7, you will need to do the `sudo ln -snf` in order to change the link to current `java`. To do so, open Terminal and issue the command:

```
sudo ln -nsf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents \
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
```

Note that the directory `jdk1.7.0_51.jdk` may change depending on the SDK version you have installed.

Now, you need to set `JAVA_HOME` to point to where `jdk_1.7.0_xx.jdk` was installed. Open again the Terminal and type:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

You can add the `export JAVA_HOME` line above in your `.bashrc` file to have java permanently in your Terminal

Comment: how do i set JAVA_HOME Variable? is there a particular place I set it in?

Comment: where am I exporting JAVA_HOME? and where will that be saved?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Do you know the SDK version that you have installed? The folder name takes the SDK version number, so the commands above might change a bit.

Comment: I installed the latest one, I think it is 51.

Comment: The variable `JAVA_HOME` will be exported on the current Terminal session. You can add it to our `.bashrc` if you want. I will adapt the commands to the last version.

Comment: @Jack you will need to open your *.profile* file with *vi* through the terminal.

Comment: I suggest you to edit `.bashrc` with a text editor instead of `.profile`.

Comment: @Trein I'd advise against using your hack and use [my](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6/19594116#19594116) version instead. It is less error prone and decidedly easier to implement. It also enables people to use both 1.6 and 1.7 without breaking either.

Comment: @Jack edit your .bash_profile
type in your terminal: vim ~/.bash_profile

Comment: I got this error after following your answer 
No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java

Answer (score 34):

tl;dr

Add the line:

`export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home'`

to the file

`~/.bash_profile`

(replace jdk1.8.0_144.jdk with your downloaded version)

then  `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 31):

Use jenv, it is like a Java environment manager. It is super easy to use and clean

For Mac, follow the steps:

```
brew install jenv

git clone https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv.git ~/.jenv
```

Installation: If you are using bash follow these steps:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

$ exec $SHELL -l
```

Add desired versions of JVM to jenv:

```
jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Check the installed versions:

```
jenv versions
```

Set the Java version you want to use by:

```
jenv global oracle64-1.6.0
```

Comment: I'm using a similar tool: https://sdkman.io/usage - IMHO much better approach than manual aliases etc

Answer (score 18):

Consider the following approach **only** to change the JDK for each and specific tab of your terminal (i.e: `iTerm`).

Having in the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` path the two following jdks

- `openjdk8u275-b01`
- `openjdk-11.0.9.1+1`

And in the `.bash_profile` file the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.9.1+1/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you open `Iterm` - with the first **Tab A** - and the following commands are executed:

```
javac -version
javac 11.0.9.1

java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1, mixed mode)
```

The output is correct and expected

But if you open a second **Tab B** and you need override the *default* JDK then write in the terminal the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk8u275-b01/Contents/Home/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_275

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_275-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

It works fine. Of course if the **Tab B** is closed or you open a new **Tab C** all work according the `.bash_profile` settings (therefore the default settings)

Answer (score 17):

Four easy steps using terminal for people who uses the default process.. :)

1. `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives you current java home. For eg: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/`
2. `cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` will take you to the folder where u normally install jdks (It might be different for your machines)
3. `ls` shows you available folders (normally it will have the version numbers, for eg: `jdk1.8.0_191.jdk        openjdk-11.0.2.jdk`)
4. `export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home'` will change the java home..

Answer (score 15):

**macOS El Capitan** or newer will choose the higher version of the JDK available in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, so in order to downgrade you may rename the file `Info.plist` to something else like `Info.plist.disabled` so that the OS will choose a previous version.

Comment: Easiest way to (: Thanks

Comment: This solution allows running VisualVM (currently not supporting JDK 16) with both JDK 15 and 16 installed.

Answer (score 13):

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
    if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
      removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
    fi
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
}
```

put this in your ~/.profile and use it in your terminal like so  `setjdk 1.8`, `setjdk 1.7`, `setjdk 9` etc etc...

If you don't have `removeFromPath` then it is:

`function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
 }`

Answer (score 13):

Run

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

you will get all the java version that you have

Example:-

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    17.0.7 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 17" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.19 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 11" /Users/abhishek.khaiwale/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.19/Contents/Home
    11.0.19 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If you need java version 11.0.19

Run

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.19`
```

[Youtube Video Link](https://youtu.be/kmccm3biY5o)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in at least one of the other answers.

Comment: @Eric Aya the answer had too many details to waste time in urgent situations.

Answer (score 12):

You can add it to your .bash_profile to have the version set by default.

```
//Open bash profile
open ~/.bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

// run bash profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks! Things of note, you must include the ` marks. and obviously, replace 1.8 with whatever version you might need. In my case 13.0.2

Answer (score 12):

Add following in your `~/.bash_profile` and set the default java version accordingly.

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'

# default to Java 8
java8
```

I am using macOS and have installed java using `brew`.

Edit:
If you are not using `bash` please update the correct shell file, example, if you are using `zsh` then it will be `~/.zshrc`

Comment: so does it mean i should put in `~/.zprofile` if I am using `~/.zshrc` (or `zsh` terminal)

Comment: Updated the answer @elliotching

Comment: Beware -- if you do not have the flagged version installed, then `java_home` will return the *default* version (unless you include the -F flag). So this can be approach can be misleading!

Comment: Not sure if I understand the concern, can you give an example? if someone is setting these variables in `.bash_profile`, then they are aware of the changes that are being done, it does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 10):

add following command to the `~/.zshenv` file

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Add the following line of code to your *.zshrc* (or *bash_profile*):

> alias j='f(){ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1` };f'

2. Save to session:

> $ source .zshrc

3. Run command (e.g. j 13, j14, j1.8...)

> $ j 1.8

**Explanation**
This is parameterised so you do not need to update the script like other solutions posted. If you do not have the JVM installed you are told. Sample cases below:

```
/Users/user/IDE/project $ j 1.8
/Users/user/IDE/project $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
/Users/user/IDE/project $ j 13
/Users/user/IDE/project $ java -version
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
/Users/user/IDE/project $ j 1.7
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
```

Comment: after I add the script to .zshrc, then run it like j 11, the terminal outputs: `f:export: not valid in this context: -v`

Answer (score 8):

Check Java version: java -version

Switch between versions: https://devqa.io/brew-install-java/

open ~/.bash_profile

export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)

export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'

source ~/.bash_profile

When we are switching to java11 or java8, java -version command is not showing the correct version.

In that case use mvn -version to see the correct java version is used for building the solution

Answer (score 7):

From the Apple's official [java_home(1) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html):

```
**USAGE**

   /usr/libexec/java_home  helps  users  set a $JAVA_HOME in their login rc files, or provides a way for
   command-line Java tools to use the most appropriate JVM which can satisfy a minimum version or archi-
   tecture  requirement.  The --exec argument can invoke tools in the selected $JAVA_HOME/bin directory,
   which is useful for starting Java command-line tools from launchd plists without hardcoding the  full
   path to the Java command-line tool.

   Usage for bash-style shells:
          $ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

   Usage for csh-style shells:
          % setenv JAVA_HOME `/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

Answer (score 7):

## JDK Switch Script

I have adapted the answer from @Alex above and wrote the following to fix the code for Java 9.

```
$ cat ~/.jdk
#!/bin/bash

#list available jdks
alias jdks="/usr/libexec/java_home -V"
# jdk version switching - e.g. `jdk 6` will switch to version 1.6
function jdk() {
  echo "Switching java version $1";

  requestedVersion=$1
  oldStyleVersion=8
  # Set the version
  if [ $requestedVersion -gt $oldStyleVersion ]; then
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1);
  else
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.$1`;
  fi

  echo "Setting JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"

  which java
  java -version;
}
```

## Switch to Java 8

```
$ jdk 8
Switching java version 8
Setting JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
/usr/bin/java
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

## Switch to Java 9

```
$ jdk 9
Switching java version 9
Setting JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
/usr/bin/java
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7):

With no additional tools to install, an easy way to have a separately installed JDK recognized as a first class member by `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` is to symlink it as follows:

```
sudo ln -s <path> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-[some-identifier].jdk
```

`<path>` is expected to be a directory containing subdirectories `Contents/Home/bin` etc.

---

A common use case is to **register the JDK/JRE included with Android Studio**:

The default location for the Java tools in recent versions of Android Studio on macOS is `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre`. We will use `jdk-android-studio.jdk` as the identifier:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-android-studio.jdk
```

Now, `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` will list it under `Matching Java Virtual Machines`:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    11.0.13 (arm64) "JetBrains s.r.o." - "OpenJDK 11.0.13" /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

Comment: this helped me in a second to solve issue in KMM "project Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Answer (score 6):

If still u are not able to set it. using this command.

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

then you have to use this one.

export JAVA_HOME=`$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

it will surely work.

Answer (score 6):

First find out where do you store the environment variables-

1. emacs
2. bash_profile
3. zshrc file

**Steps to Set up the environment variable :-**

1. Download the jdk from JAVA
2. install it by double click
3. Now set-up environment variables in your file

   a. For **emacs.profile** you can use this [link](http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/) OR see the screenshot below

[image]

**b. For ZSH profile setup -**

```
1. export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home

2. source ~/.zshrc - Restart zshrc to reflect the changes.

3. echo $JAVA_HOME - make sure path is set up properly 
   ----> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home

4. java -version 

   -->  java version "1.8.0_112"  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
```

All set Now you can easily upgrade or degrade the JAVA version..

Answer (score 6):

Previously I used alias'es in .zshrc for easy switching between versions but today I use SDKMAN.
SDKMAN can also handle setting default java for the system, and downloading and installing new java versions.

Once sdkman is installed you can then do commands similar to what is possible with the nvm tool for handling node versions.

`sdk list java` will list the java versions available on your system as well as available online for installation including their identifier that you can use in the `sdk use`, `sdk default` and `sdk install` commands.

e.g. to install Amazon Corretto 11.0.8 and ask if it should be the new default do this:
`sdk install java 11.0.8-amzn`

A feature I also use regularly is the `.sdkmanrc` file.
If you place that in a directory on your machine and run the `sdk env` command in the directory then you can configure tool versions used only in that directory. It is also possible to make sdkman switch tool versions automatically using the `sdkman_auto_env=true` configuration.

sdkman also supports handling other tools for the JVM such as gradle, kotlin, maven and more.

For more information check out https://sdkman.io/usage#env

Answer (score 4):

If you are using fish and you are using mac and you want to be able to switch between JDK's, then below works for me on mac.

@kenglxn's answer didn't work for me and I figured out it bcos didn't set -g which is global !

Put below under ~/.config/fish/config.fish

```
alias j8="jhome  -v 1.8.0_162"
alias j9="jhome  -v 9.0.1"

function jhome
    set -g -x JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home $argv)
    echo "JAVA_HOME:" $JAVA_HOME
    echo "java -version:"
    java -version
end

funcsave jhome
```

To know which version /minor version you have installed, you can do :

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V                                                                              579ms  Wed 14 Feb 11:44:01 2018
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    9.0.1, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_162, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_121, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 4):

This will guide you on how to switch JAVA versions on your MacOS device. This can be useful for working with apps which don’t work with updated JAVA versions. For example, applications such as Cassandra will only work with JAVA version 8.

First, you need to make certain you have multiple JAVA versions installed.

Open a new Terminal window and input:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Your output should look like:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_201, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Note that there are two JDKs available. If you don’t notice the Java version you need to switch to, download and install the appropriate one from here (JDK 8 is represented as 1.8) . Once you have installed the appropriate JDK, repeat this step.

2. Take note of the JDK version you want to switch to. For example, “11.0” and “1.8” are the JDK versions available in the example above.
3. Switch to the desired version. For example, if you wish to switch to JDK 8, input the following line:

   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

   For 11.0, switch “1.8” with “11.0”
4. Check your JDK version by inputting into Terminal:

   java -version

If you have followed all the steps correctly, the JDK version should correlate with the one you specified in the last step.

5. (Optional) To make this the default JDK version, input the following in Terminal:

   open ~/.bash_profile

Then, add your Terminal input from step 3 to this file:

## SWITCH TO JAVA VERSION 8

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Save and close the file.

Done.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple versions and you want to run something by using a specific version, use this example:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_75 --exec java -jar you-file.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @markhellewell answer I created a couple of alias functions that will do it for you. Just add these to your shell startup file

```
#list available jdks
alias jdks="/usr/libexec/java_home -V"
# jdk version switching - e.g. `jdk 6` will switch to version 1.6
function jdk() { 
  echo "Switching java version"; 
  export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.$1`; 
  java -version; 
}
```

https://gist.github.com/Noyabronok/0a90e1f3c52d1aaa941013d3caa8d0e4

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it on my **Linux** *(Ubuntu / Mint mate)*, I guess Mac can do it similarly.

---

### Install & config

**Steps:**

- **[Basic - part]**
- Download jdk *(the **.tgz** file)* by hand.
- Uncompress & rename properly, at a proper location.
  e.g  `/mnt/star/program/java/jdk-1.8`
- Make a soft link, which will be changed to switch java version later.
  e.g `ln -s /mnt/star/program/java/jdk-1.8 /mnt/star/program/java/java`
  Thus `/mnt/star/program/java/java` is the soft link.
- Set `JAVA_HOME` in a start script.
  Could use file like `/etc/profile.d/eric.sh`, or just use `~/.bashrc`.
  e.g `JAVA_HOME=/mnt/star/program/java/java`
- Then open a new bash shell. `java -version` should print the java version.
- **[More version - part]**
- Download & install more Java version, as need, similar as above steps.
  e.g
  `/mnt/star/program/java/jdk-11`
- **[Switch - part]**
- In `~/.bashrc`, define variable for various Java version.
  e.g
  `_E_JAVA_HOME_11='/mnt/star/program/java/jdk-11'`
  `_E_JAVA_HOME_8='/mnt/star/program/java/jdk-8'`
  `# dir of default version,`
  `_E_JAVA_HOME_D=$_E_JAVA_HOME_8`
- In `~/.bashrc`, define command to switch Java version.
  e.g
  `## switch java version,`
  `alias jv11="rm $JAVA_HOME; ln -s $_E_JAVA_HOME_11 $JAVA_HOME"`
  `alias jv8="rm $JAVA_HOME; ln -s $_E_JAVA_HOME_8 $JAVA_HOME"`
  `# default java version,`
  `alias jvd="rm $JAVA_HOME; ln -s $_E_JAVA_HOME_D $JAVA_HOME"`
  `alias jv="java -version"`
- In terminal, `source ~/.bashrc` to make the changes take effect.
- Then could switch using the defined commands.

---

### Commands - from above config

**Commands:**

- `jv11`
  Switch to Java 11
- `jv8`
  Switch to Java 8
- `jvd`
  Switch to default Java version, which is denoted by `_E_JAVA_HOME_D` defined above.
- `jv`
  Show java version.

**Example output:**

```
eric@eric-pc:~$ jv
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

eric@eric-pc:~$ jv11
eric@eric-pc:~$ jv
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

eric@eric-pc:~$ jvd
eric@eric-pc:~$ jv
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

eric@eric-pc:~$
```

---

### Mechanism

- It switch by changing the soft link, which is used as `JAVA_HOME`.

---

### Tips

- On my machine when install jdk by hand, I keep the minor version, then make a soft link with the major version but without the minor version.
  e.g
  // this is the actual dir,
  `jdk1.8.0_191`

  // this is a soft link to `jdk1.8.0_191`
  `jdk-8`

  // this is a soft link to `jdk-8` or `jdk-11`
  `java`
- I define command alias in `~/.bashrc`, but define variable in a separate file.
  I am using `~/.eric_var` to define the variables, and `~/.bashrc` will source it (e.g `source $HOME/.eric_var`).

Answer (score 2):

add this function to bashrc or zshrc, `java-change [version]` to choose the JDK

```sh
# set and change java versions
function java-change() {
  echo "----- old java version -----"
  java -version
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
  echo "----- new java version -----"
  java -version
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple answer:

1. Run and get all the installed JDK path

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

2. Run direct commands from [jenv.be](https://jenv.be)

```
git clone https://github.com/jenv/jenv.git ~/.jenv #Linux/macOS
OR
brew install jenv #macOS

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc

jenv add PATH_FROM_STEP_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use sdkman to manage different version of java as suggested in previous answers. However, no one mentioned the easy way to switch. run below command to see what all version in installed. I have installed java 8 and java 17 using sdkman.

```
sdk list java
```

output

```
Oracle        |     | 20.0.2       | oracle  |            | 20.0.2-oracle       
           |     | 20.0.1       | oracle  |            | 20.0.1-oracle       
           | >>> | 17.0.8       | oracle  | installed  | 17.0.8-oracle
```

Right now my default version is set to java 8. If i want to switch to java 17. Use below command for it.

```
sdk use java 17.0.8-oracle
```

Now you can see default version is java 17

```
% java -version             
java version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this [fish](https://fishshell.com) function [I wrote](https://github.com/anothernode/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.config/fish/functions/javav.fish):

```
function javav
  set min_version 8
  set max_version 99
  set java_home_cmd '/usr/libexec/java_home 2>/dev/null --failfast --version'

  if ! test (eval $java_home_cmd $argv)
    echo "Version not found"
    return 1
  end

  for current_version in (seq $min_version $max_version)
    set path_to_remove (eval $java_home_cmd $current_version)
    if ! test -z $path_to_remove
      echo 'Removing' $path_to_remove 'from PATH'
      set PATH (string match --invert $path_to_remove/bin $PATH)
    end
  end

  echo 'Setting up env for Java' $argv
  set -x JAVA_HOME (eval $java_home_cmd $argv)
  set PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin $PATH
end
```

It basically automates the step in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/1225882), similarly to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875847/1225882), but also taking care of setting the PATH.

Just put it in `.config/fish/functions/` and then use it like this:

```
javav 11 # Sets to Java 11
javav 16 # Sets to Java 16
```

Answer (score -1):

HI you can use this command
`sudo update-alternatives --config java`
then you can use the one you like with number
for example i have 3 java in my linux
so i pick 0 , 1 or etc
i hope help for others

Comment: Does `update-alternatives` exist on Mac?

Comment: I don't think `update-alternatives` exists on Mac, as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76704/how-to-set-alternatives-in-10-8. Worth checking :)

Answer (score -6):

TOO EASY SOLUTION: What a headache - this was a quick easy solution that worked for me.

Mac OS Sierra Version 10.12.13

1. Use the shortcut keys: CMD+SHIFT+G - type in "/Library/"
2. Find the JAVA folder
3. Right Click Java Folder = Move to Trash (Password Required)
4. Install: 
   Java SE Development Kit 8 jdk-8u131-macosx-x64.dmg | [Download Javascript SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
5. Make sure the new JAVA folder appears in /LIBRARY/
6. Install Eclipse | [Install Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2)
7. Boom Done