# Homebrew cask option not recognized?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am following an online resource for installing two Mac utilities

http://www.economyofeffort.com/2014/08/11/beyond-ctrl-remap-make-that-caps-lock-key-useful/

Here is the pertinent section:

> Install both Karabiner and Seil. (Here again, if you use Homebrew
> Cask, you can do this with
>
> $ brew **cask** install karabiner and
>
> $ brew **cask** install seil

But the *cask* option is not recognized?

```
06:51:35/shared $brew cask install seil
Error: Unknown command: cask
```

Then, just for laughs I tried the command without the *cask*:

```
06:55:01/shared $brew install seil
Error: No available formula for seil
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
Caskroom/cask/seil
```

It is not clear what the last line of output even means: nothing seems to have happened on the system.

I am on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1301, accepted):

As of 2021, the answer to this question for me was that instead of

```
brew cask install myprogram
```

I should run:

```
brew install --cask myprogram
```

Comment: I was trying to use it but I think you don't need to pass cask anymore.
I just hit:
`brew install spotify`
It worked for me.

Comment: Found link in homebrew's Github discussion with explanation of behavior change:  https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/340#discussioncomment-232364

Comment: "All brew cask commands have been deprecated in favour of brew commands (with --cask) when necessary" read on https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/

Comment: cask was warned that would be obsolete and removed in future brew versions, and should be replaced by `--cask`

Comment: nice ```brew install --cask font-fira-code```

Comment: @Ederson-Badeca I still needed cask to install docker for desktop.
```brew install --cask docker```

Comment: `brew install cask your-package` worked for me instead

Comment: Unless there are conflicting cask and formulae names (check handbrake as an example using brew search handbrake) then the standard format of brew install nameOfYourProgram should work. Alternatively, you should be using the --cask flag according to brew install -h which reports '--cask' and not 'cask'.

Answer (score 53):

As of 2021 use this command instead:

```
brew install --cask your-package
```

Comment: This is not correct, this will install the packages `cask` and `your-package`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66081492/826486 for the correct answer.

Comment: it's correct for me too on MacOS M1 2021

Comment: wow, this answer is extremely wrong. Can this please be deleted or something?

Answer (score 30):

UPD: since the command `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask` gives you the following error `Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.` please run `brew install homebrew/cask`

To use `brew cask` you should have it installed, this is a extension of brew, is not native.

To install it you need to run `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask` from your command line

[Homebrew Cask Github](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask)

Comment: `caskroom/cask` was moved, i need to use `homebrew/cask` instead.

`brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.`

Comment: I had the same issue @KDFinal I finally got it to work by changing the way I reference the file I was wanting to install to: "brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8"

Comment: the homebrew/cask is worked on me, but it still get error after I ran cask

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue. Now you should use:

```
brew install --cask <package>
```

instead of:

```
brew cask install <package>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also just `brew install Caskroom/cask/seil`. It will automatically tap the correct cask for you :)

Comment: `No available formula or cask with the name "caskroom/cask/seil".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.`

Comment: This particular package has been obsoleted https://github.com/tekezo/Seil

Answer (score 8):

Use brew install --cask <package_name>

It worked for me after trying multiple permutations and combinations.

Comment: duplicate of  answer from @DolDurma

Answer (score 7):

None of these answers—despite some of them being correct at the moment—are showing their work and so may become no longer correct if this changes again.

I ran into this issue, stumbled on this page, and it was enough to get me curious about the change in command line and where that might be documented. Turns out you can go right here:

https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/

and any of those you click on will show you the current command to use. So, for instance, the iterm2 page:

https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/iterm2

right at the top it's got the correct command to use so if they ever change it, you'll see what the new syntax is.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You are right with your examples. Also, if you go to brew.sh, in the cask section, it lists the "new" command `$ brew install --cask firefox`, while earlier, the format of the command was e.g. `brew cask install skype`. Apparently this was changed in 2.6.0. The blog/release notes https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0 mention: "All brew cask commands have been deprecated in favour of brew commands (with --cask) when necessary", I did not find further details why they made this change though.

Answer (score 6):

`brew tap caskroom/cask`

`brew install brew-cask`

Now, you are ready to `brew cask`.

Comment: `brew` didn't find the brew-cask formula, but did find `brew install homebrew/completions/brew-cask-completion` instead. That enabled `brew cask` for me.

Comment: **Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.**

Answer (score 6):

@JeremyJohn answer is out to date, for installing `Android` sdk you should use this command:

```sh
brew install --cask android-sdk
```

Answer (score 5):

With macOS Big Sur , running
`brew install ...`  will works

Answer (score 4):

Install it with this command:

```
brew install brew-cask-completion
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't why the highest voted answer doesn't work for me. But you can do something like `brew install homebrew/cask/appName`

Answer (score 4):

Since [Homebrew 2.6.0 released in 2020.12.01](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/), **`brew cask` has been deprecated and later dropped**.

Homebrew not only manages TUI packages (formulae from the `homebrew-core` repo), it's also capable of managing GUI packages (casks from `homebrew-cask` repo). In the old days, `brew` commands like `brew list`, `brew outdated` take effect only on formula. Cask operations are separated into `brew cask`.

Homebrew has **prioritized support for casks** since 2.6.0. All the `brew` commands take effect on both formulae and casks. **You must specify `--formula` or `--cask` explicitly to indicate them separately**.

```sh
# Some examples
brew list # both formula and cask
brew list --formula
brew list --cask

brew outdated # both formula and cask
brew outdated --formula
brew outdated --cask
```

Answer (score 2):

For me,

`brew install <program_name>` has worked fine till now.

For example, I was trying to install Oracle Virtual Box and the formula for it was listed as

`$ brew cask install virtualbox`.

But, `$ brew install virtualbox` worked just fine. I found that it was installing the application as cask as shown in the screenshot.[image]

I think `homebrew` automatically takes care of the cask dependency.

Comment: Why do I get this error: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following the below steps.

**Step 1:** Run `brew install --help`

*Might show something like this.*

```
Usage: brew install [options] formula|cask [...]

Install a formula or cask. Additional options specific to a formula may be
appended to the command.
```

**Step 2:** follow the hint ot help create the command and execute.

```
brew install cask chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
brew cask install yourprogram
```

I have run:

```
brew install --cask yourprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to check is that it may be installed but not linked:

```
$ brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
Warning: caskroom/cask/brew-cask-0.59.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

This is easily fixed by running:

```
$ brew link brew-cask
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. Had my head scratching and finally figured out and use the commands like:

brew commands --cask

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**!!!!**

**`brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.**

*Example Syntax:-*

Use:

```
brew install --cask <package_name>
```

Instead of:

```
brew cask install <package_name>
```