# Error: Unknown command: cask || despite the use of multiple instance trials

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am not able to do anything anymore. I keep getting the error `Error: Unknown command: cask` even though I have previously used a lot of different installations from this link: [Homebrew cask option not recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413621/homebrew-cask-option-not-recognized)

**NONE OF THEM HELPED!**

For example I get this output:

[image]

After the instance I want to apply this command: `brew cask install cscreen` to then go to `cscreen -l`. However, I keep getting the above error...

Please help.
I want to use this because without it I am not able to work on a closed MacBook because when I close the monitor it goes back to the dreaded setting of 75Hz.

Regards!

Answer (score 59):

I was having a similar issue running `brew cask install [...]`. I am running macOS Catalina v10.15.7. I used `brew install --cask [...]` and it worked for me. In your case:

`brew install --cask cscreen`

Comment: This is way! It also worked for me. I'm on Catalina as well.

Comment: Works on Big Sur too

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Monterey. Just omit the cask.

Answer (score 29):

For anyone like me landing here where effreety's answer does not work, try whatever command you are trying to run without `cask`.

`cask` is [no longer a `brew` command](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/902#discussioncomment-398348).

Comment: `cask` is used to install GUI applications. Although it's no longer a command, it still can be used as an option as shown by @effreety. Just now, I installed Docker successfully using `brew install --cask docker`

Answer (score 1):

Run your brew command without "cask".

Example:
Instead of `brew cask install graphql-playground` try `brew install graphql-playground`

Comment: This worked for me. '--cask' did not work