# How to resolve Github build R 3.5 cask error?

Tags: r, github, rstudio, homebrew-cask

I recently installed git and incorporated it with R studio so that I can use github's version control system. I am new to git and github, so I am out of my depth when it comes to figuring out how to resolve errors.
The issue I have is that my "push" actions keep failing. Attached is a screenshot of the code that runs in github, and the associated error. Each action fails when trying to set up R 3.5 with the error, "Error: Unknown command: cask."
I looked at the HomeBrew page on github but haven't seen any issues similar to mine. I see some code lines I could run to try to update cask but I don't know where I am supposed to run them. Homebrew gives the following line to run to update cask: "brew bump-cask-pr --version <new_version> <outdated_cask>". But this doesn't run in r or gitbash so I'm not sure where I am supposed to be inputting it.
Any insight is much appreciated!

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUc1P.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homebrew cask option not recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413621/homebrew-cask-option-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0):

If you get `Error: Unknown command: cask`, it's because [`cask` is no longer a separate command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66081492/4855849) within Homebrew.

Just run (in your Terminal):

```sh
brew install rstudio
```

or

```
brew install --cask rstudio
```

This being said, I don't understand your precise issue. I don't think you need to install `gfortran` directly (it comes as a dependency with `r`), and more importantly, `gfortran` is not a cask...

If you want to use R and need some basic tools, just install R, RStudio and Git (`brew install r rstudio git`), and you should be fine.

Don't use `brew bump-cask-pr`. That's for maintenance of cask formulas (to signal Homebrew there is a new version of an app to update their database). Not necessary for a beggining user.