# Change Android Studio doclet version

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc, doclet

I need to generate the javadoc for a Library in Android Studio.

The problem is that, when I start to create the doc, I see the following logs:

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_31
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
[...]
1 error
javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.FunctionalInterface not found
```

I don't know exactly what is the problem. I think it is the doclet version (it takes by default 1.8.0_31); I tried to modify it but I did not succeed... any help?

I am using Mac OSX and Android Studio 1.2.2

Comment: I used this answer to change the current Java version on MAC: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x/24657630#24657630