# Switch Mac JAVA_HOME fail

Tags: java, android, macos

I am compiling android system source and come across a problem.

```
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version of java.

Your version is: java version "1.8.0_45".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
https://source.android.com/source/download.html
```

I open terminal to try to see my java version.

## 1, When I input /usr/libexec/java_home and it tells me 1.8

```
QuinnChens-MacBook-Pro:Android4.4 Quinn$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

## 2, When I input java -version and it tells me 1.8

```
QuinnChens-MacBook-Pro:Android4.4 Quinn$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

## 3, I write the below line in .profile to try to switch JDK version.

```
# Mac  JDK 6 
export JAVA_6_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6 )

# Mac  JDK 8
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 )

#alias dymatically switch  JDK 
alias jdk6="export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_6_HOME"
alias jdk8="export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME"
```

## 4, I run source .profile and run 'jdk6' and run java -version

```
QuinnChens-MacBook-Pro:Android4.4 Quinn$ source ~/.profile
QuinnChens-MacBook-Pro:Android4.4 Quinn$ jdk6
QuinnChens-MacBook-Pro:Android4.4 Quinn$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

## 5, But when I input /usr/libexec/java_home and it still tells me 1.8

```
QuinnChens-MacBook-Pro:Android4.4 Quinn$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

## 6, And my problem still exists.It tell me My mac still use JDK 1.8 instead of 1.6

```
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version of java.

Your version is: java version "1.8.0_45".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
https://source.android.com/source/download.html
```

## Question 1:

How can I switch JDK version in my mac? Is the way I use correct?

## Question 2:

Why does "/usr/libexec/java_home" not change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x , If you try this and still doesn't work, Just uninstall the JDK temporarily, which should be 1.8