# Play Store: Can't install app, (Error code: -103)

Tags: google-play

Yesterday I published my app in Play Store. All went well till today. When I try to install my app from Play Store, it downloads it but when installing it it says:

"My_application" can't be installed. Try again, and if the problem continues, get troubleshooting. (Error code: -103)

I tried installing on multiple devices.

Edit:
On some devices it goes through installation process as it should and all goes well.

On others it gives the above error message.

Comment: I've found the solution!

So, the problem for me was basically compatibility issue with some of the handsets. Before publishing, when I was signing the app (.apk file), I did that with "jarsigner" in JDK1.8(overlooked that tiiiiiiiinnyyyyy mistake that gave me a whole day of headache).

Then I went back, signed the app again(this time) with jarsigner in JDK1.6 and it worked!

So this morning I tested the app on bunch of devices that gave me Error code: -103 yesterday while installing, and all went smooth.

Best regards,
Mladen

Comment: well done on solving the issue. it would be useful for you to post this as an answer for others to benefit ( also possibility of upvotes )

Comment: I am facing the same problem first I did with jarsinger 1.7 and second time I did with jarsinger 1.6 but facing still same issue...

Answer (score 17):

Older Android devices are unable to recognize **SHA256** hash funcitons. Adding:

`-sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1`

as parameters to **jarsigner** should solve the issue even when using JDK 1.8.

Comment: Do you know if this affects any newer devices to break?

Comment: how do I do this via android studio?

Answer (score 0):

As @mladen-gavrić comment his own question, downgrade to `java JDK` version `1.6.` solves the issue.

SE with `$ java -v`with version is currently running which will output something like the following:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

See this excellent answer how to downgrade with the `JDK 1.6.` already installed previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/2797243