# Playstore Cordova App Error 103

Tags: android, cordova

I published my App in the Google Playstore.  Its working well on a s4mini and the s6 but on the s3mini there is always a fault After downloading. 'App was not installed... 103'
I have tested it on two s3minis with android 4.1.2. What can be the reason that it not work? Maybe the min. sdk Version? If that, how do I have to change it? (I think that this sdk Version is 22 or 23)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Store: Can't install app, (Error code: -103)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149140/play-store-cant-install-app-error-code-103)

Comment: Ok thats the same Problem but i dont unterstand the solution i am Bad in english:/. What do I have to do?