# How can I change the SHA256 to SHA1 of apk signer

Tags: android, apk, signing, jarsigner

I have apk file signed by SHA256.

Step1) I deleted the sign,

```
zip -d ./myapp.apk 'META-INF/*'
```

step2) Check sign was correctly deleted

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile ./myapp.apk
```

Step3) I re-signed my application with SHA1

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android.keystore ./my.apk mykey
```

Step4) Check

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile ./takiyamaAR.apk
```

However it shows

```
 MD5:  19:3F:E4:D8:BB:BB:0A:85:85:CB:99:F2:37:54:24:EB
 SHA1: AD:1D:26:E9:A5:74:14:76:F4:EA:36:D2:7F:F6:9E:E9:92:CB:B2:74
 SHA256: A6:07:46:9C:3A:FD:38:A0:7D:9C:35:91:AD:E7:83:3F:AD:C4:84:C1:AE:36:C5:BD:A0:AE:F3:62:D9:8C:57:FF
  Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
 version: 3
```

It looks like still SHA256.
I surely signed with SHA1 on Step3.

How can I use SHA1 instead of SHA256?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use an outdated (and now unsafe) message digest function?

Comment: Since some of our customers complaint about error code 103. I found out the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149140/play-store-cant-install-app-error-code-103)

Comment: Do you find any solution on this?

Comment: I have gave up to making SHA1 ..... I found work around way, not use the library which require SHA1