# WearPkgInstallerService: Package install failed. returnCode -103

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wearables

I have developed an application for SmartWatch with version of Wear OS 1.5 and up. At the time of distributing the application I have included it together with the main application in the same apk.

I have compiled a release version and installed it, when synchronizing the applications with the SmartWatch, through the debug console I get the following error message.

```
05-03 18:06:55.637 665-1884/? I/PkgMgrInstallUtil: Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/com.sergio.application/wearable/com.sergio.application/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.wear.WearPackageInstallerService (has extras) } for com.sergio.application
05-03 18:06:56.269 1701-1890/? I/WearPkgInstallerService: Sent installation request for es.usal.bisite.ebikemotion
05-03 18:06:56.281 1722-1732/? D/DefContainer: Copying /data/user/0/com.google.android.packageinstaller/files/tmp/com.sergio.application.apk to base.apk
05-03 18:06:56.528 1701-1743/? E/WearPkgInstallerService: Package install failed com.sergio.application, returnCode -103
05-03 18:06:56.528 1701-1743/? I/WearablePkgInstaller: Sending removeFromPermStore to ShowPermsService Intent { act=android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE cmp=com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.ShowPermsService (has extras) } for com.sergio.application
```

Indicating that the application could not be installed, without giving details of the problem and only indicates the error code **-103**.

I have taken into account the basic considerations for the development of applications wear.

- Both the main application and the SmartWatch have the same
  **application id.**.
- The permissions required in the SmartWatch    application are also
  explicitly configured in the main application.

etc..

The application can be implemented correctly in "**standalone**" mode, directly from Android Studio.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/passsy/gradle-GitVersioner/master/git-versioner.gradle'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sergio.application"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${rootProject.support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:${rootProject.support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:${rootProject.play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.play_services_version}"


    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.2.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.patloew.rxwear:rxwear:1.3.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

    //GLIDE
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'

    //ButterKnife
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${rootProject.butterknife}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${rootProject.butterknife}"

    implementation "io.reactivex:rxjava:${rootProject.rx_java}"
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxandroid:${rootProject.rx_android}"

    //TIMBER
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${rootProject.timber}"

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.12@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Versions used:

```
support_library_version = "27.1.1"
constraint_layout_version = '1.1.0'
play_services_version = "15.0.0"
```

Next I show the manifest file of the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sergio.application">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationWear"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="api_key"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="api_key" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"/>

        <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"/>

        <service android:name=".DisconnectListenerService"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help me solve this problem? . Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149140/play-store-cant-install-app-error-code-103

Comment: It's similar, but it's not the same problem. I can install the application wear with adb without problems directly on the device. The problem is when it is included in the apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is due to a confusion, I had understood that when generating a "**release**" compilation for the app module the configuration to make the apk signature (keystore, alias, password) was propagated to the module wear. When generating the apk from **Android Studio** I have no problem, error 103 occurs to me when generating the apk from CLI with `./gradlew assembleRelease`

The solution is therefore very simple

Include the following configuration in the gradle of the module wear:

```
signingConfigs {

        release {
            storeFile file("./keystore_secret")
            storePassword "myPassword"
            keyAlias "MyAlias"
            keyPassword "myPassword"
        }

    }



buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

I hope it can be useful to someone too.