# Change JDK version from 1.8 to 1.6

Tags: java

I want ot change my jdk versiob from 1.8 to 1.6 but how do have to do this?
I read this post [How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x/24657630#24657630) which is what I think the solution, but when I am goign to 'C:\Program Files\Java' there are only two folder, one jdk1.8.0_65 and jdk1.8.0_73 there is no jdk1.6 so how and where can I get this there?

Comment: you can download old java release from the oracle site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Comment: Did I need SE or Environemtal?

Comment: you currently have 2 JDKs installed on your system, so you probably need it there (development kit)

Comment: But now I have to install things is that right thats an exe not an folder.

Comment: choose the jdk 6.45 and yes you have an exe in the list

Comment: Ok now thers a folder like jdk1.8.0_73 should i do now this in CMD?:

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=`C:\Program Files\Java -v sdk1.6.0_45` ???

Answer (score 0):

Install the Java version you want to use.

You can use jenv, it is like a Java environment manager. It is super easy to use and clean

For Mac, follow the steps:

```
brew install jenv

git clone https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv.git ~/.jenv
```

Installation: If you are using bash follow these steps:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

$ exec $SHELL -l
```

Add desired versions of JVM to jenv:

```
jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Check the installed versions:

```
jenv versions
```

Set the Java version you want to use by:

```
jenv global oracle64-1.6.0
```