# Error Found (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError) in Selenium With PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, automated-tests

I am trying to setup Selenium with PHPUnit for automated testing, but when I want to execute jar file using this command

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar "
```

it is showing this error:

[image]

How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: what do you get when you run `java -version`?

Comment: After run java -version , it is showing http://prntscr.com/bdva4i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG), selenium requires Java 7 (1.7) or 8 (1.8) since release 2.47, while the screenshot you posted shows version 6 (1.6). So either you need to install Java to 7 or 8, or make it default, if it's already installed. Since it appears that you are on MacBook-Pro, check the following instructions: [How do I install Java for my Mac?](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml). If java 7 or 8 already installed, check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x) on how to make it a default.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to follow what you said.

Comment: I have upgraded the java version (http://prntscr.com/bdwdrm), but It is showing http://prntscr.com/bdwcae 
Why not showing like this http://prntscr.com/bdwd88 ?

Comment: it's quite different selenium version (2.25 vs. 2.53, they are 4 years apart), so log could have changed of course. But it says "Selenium server is up and running", so why don't you try to use it?

Comment: Okay I am trying. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this looks like a completely different question. Post it separately and someone will hopefully answer