# Can I change multiple Java versions(1.7 and 1.8) in Java Control Panel in MAC like Windows 10?

Tags: java, macos, versions

I had installed Java 1.8 in my Macbook and then installed 1.7.

But in the "Java Control Panel(in System Preference)", Java 1.7 is not shown..
[in Mac book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT2QZ.png)

I have another PC(Windows 10) and it shows multiple Java versions in Java Control panel, but in MAC OS, there is only one Java version.

In the Past,
I modified ~/.bash_profile to change Java version(like windows system environment variable), it is inconvenient for me.

In Windows, Java control panel is a grate tool for "changing different Java version". So I want to use it in my Macbook, but it is now properly work as i expected...

How can I show up every Java versions in the Java Control Panel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't used this myself but I heard [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) can accomplish something like this.

Comment: Dear @BillF Thank you for your comment! But i want to use Java Control Panel originally.... T_T

Comment: The existing Java Control Panel is a disgrace. The old system utility to manage multiple versions of Java was removed since 10.8.2. If you want to install multiple versions of JDK, and have control on "the system-default version", perhaps [this answer could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x/44169445#44169445). (Warning: this still involves fiddling with files). Also check out other answers, but if I understand correctly they won't be satisfactory. Like you I'm still looking for the perfect answer :-/