# python pip install error language_check

Tags: python-2.7, pip

When I am trying to install `sudo pip install language_check`
I got this error:

```
Collecting language_check
Downloading language-check-1.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Installed /tmp/pip-build-_cYgOq/language-check/.eggs/3to2-1.1.1-py2.7.‌​
egg error in language-check setup command: package_data must be a dictionary 
mapping package names to lists of wildcard patterns
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_cYgOq/language-check/
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the entire error message, all lines.

Comment: Collecting language_check
  Downloading language-check-1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    
    Installed /tmp/pip-build-_cYgOq/language-check/.eggs/3to2-1.1.1-py2.7.egg
    error in language-check setup command: package_data must be a dictionary mapping package names to lists of wildcard patterns
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_cYgOq/language-check/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `language-check`. They [fixed it at 23 March](https://github.com/myint/language-check/commit/590cb43cee617fa58d8b18aedd94506341c61b8a) but didn't include in any release yet ([release 1.0 was from 21 March](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/language-check/1.0)).

Download the sources from Github and install with

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: hi. can you provide the link of the github repository

Comment: The 1st in my answer. Can also be found at the page for the second link. That's where I found it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you install the latest version of Python, [python3.6.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-362/) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone -b patch-1 https://github.com/SpartorA/language-check.git

python setup.py install
```

Above will work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to **successfully install `language-check` in my Python 3.7 environment on MacOS** as follows:

1. **Check Java installation** :

- for `language-check`, Java 8 is expected
- For MacOS: Follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630

---

2. **Install** `language-check`

`pip install language-check`, won't directly work, you would have to:

- Install from a forked & fixed repo for `language-check`
- `pip install git+https://github.com/MCFreddie777/language-check.git`

---