# pip install language-check not working

Tags: python, django, dependencies, pip, setup.py

I get this error when I do `pip install language-check`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/j6/yr6zgb4d1w308jkpc27p2t9w0000gn/T/pip-build-ymwzmypp/language-check/setup.py", line 595, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/private/var/folders/j6/yr6zgb4d1w308jkpc27p2t9w0000gn/T/pip-build-ymwzmypp/language-check/setup.py", line 590, in main
    run_setup_hooks(config)
  File "/private/var/folders/j6/yr6zgb4d1w308jkpc27p2t9w0000gn/T/pip-build-ymwzmypp/language-check/setup.py", line 561, in run_setup_hooks
    language_tool_hook(config)
  File "/private/var/folders/j6/yr6zgb4d1w308jkpc27p2t9w0000gn/T/pip-build-ymwzmypp/language-check/setup.py", line 584, in language_tool_hook
    download_lt()
  File "/private/var/folders/j6/yr6zgb4d1w308jkpc27p2t9w0000gn/T/pip-build-ymwzmypp/language-check/download_lt.py", line 117, in download_lt
    version = get_newest_possible_languagetool_version()
  File "/private/var/folders/j6/yr6zgb4d1w308jkpc27p2t9w0000gn/T/pip-build-ymwzmypp/language-check/download_lt.py", line 81, in get_newest_possible_languagetool_version
    universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/java', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I've looked at this question [python pip install error language_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206833/python-pip-install-error-language-check) and followed the instructions to install `python setup.py install` and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 595, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "setup.py", line 590, in main
    run_setup_hooks(config)
  File "setup.py", line 561, in run_setup_hooks
    language_tool_hook(config)
  File "setup.py", line 584, in language_tool_hook
    download_lt()
  File "/Users/allyzamarquez/ben/language_check/language-check/download_lt.py", line 117, in download_lt
    version = get_newest_possible_languagetool_version()
  File "/Users/allyzamarquez/ben/language_check/language-check/download_lt.py", line 81, in get_newest_possible_languagetool_version
universal_newlines=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/java', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/java -version` return? Looks like that's a factor here.

Comment: Installation successfully under environment:                                               64-bit
python version "3.6.1"
java version "1.8.0_144"

Comment: Ah 'No Java runtime present, requesting install.' I went to Oracle's website, installed JRE and it says that Java is installed on my computer.

Comment: `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460277/error-installing-language-check-using-pip-install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460277/error-installing-language-check-using-pip-install

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 must be used until language-check fixes their installer script:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

pip install language-check
```