# Error installing language-check using pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pip

i am having an error installing language-check when I use pip. My python version is 3.9.5.

i have tried putting these commands into powershell as well as a few more and they have all given me the same error. I am not sure how to proceed

```
pip install language-check
pip install language_check
pip install --upgrade language-check
pip install --upgrade language-check
```

Error that I got

```
PS D:\Python> pip install --upgrade language-check
Collecting language-check
  Using cached language-check-1.1.tar.gz (33 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: language-check
  Building wheel for language-check (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'd:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rodge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rodge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\rodge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-t0bpvet6'
       cwd: C:\Users\rodge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\
  Complete output (4 lines):
  Could not parse Java version from """openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
  """.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for language-check
  Running setup.py clean for language-check
Failed to build language-check
Installing collected packages: language-check
    Running setup.py install for language-check ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rodge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rodge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rodge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-52viif_0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\python\Include\language-check'
         cwd: C:\Users\rodge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\
    Complete output (4 lines):
    Could not parse Java version from """openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
    """.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rodge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rodge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q4dwn2qj\\language-check_ee739d071d0c47e9b1b2023e1ac3ecda\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rodge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-52viif_0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\python\Include\language-check' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like an [old known bug](https://github.com/myint/language-check/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Could+not+parse+Java+version). The package seems to be abandoned, last commit was on Feb 16, 2019.

The package [was forked](https://github.com/myint/language-check/issues/31#issuecomment-622234576), updated and published under the name `language-tool-python`: https://pypi.org/project/language-tool-python/

Try

```
pip install language-tool-python
```

Answer (score 0):

As of right now this is a known and [open issue](https://github.com/myint/language-check/issues/59) on the `language-check` [git repo](https://github.com/myint/language-check/). It's caused by the wrong regex for the Java version, and is caused by JDK version >= 8

To fix this you can either try to use the forked project as @phd mentioned or

You can uninstall JDK 11 and install JDK 6 instead.