# React Native error: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."

Tags: react-native, gradle

I'm working on MacOS and just starting with `react-native`.

One of the first steps to get started is to run: `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`. But I'm getting this error:

```bash
react-native run-android
```

Result:

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/ric/myprojs/albums/node_modules (6ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

This is what I get when I run `java --version`:

```bash
java --version
```

Result:

```
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
mbp:albums ric$ java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

### Edit

My javac version:

```bash
javac --version
```

Result:

```
javac 9.0.1
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: can you run `javac -version` too in terminal please

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11755) it is a bit old but might be related to either java version or gradle.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

In your **`PROJECT_PATH/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file, update your `distributionUrl`** to the following:

```gradle
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip
```

See related [gradle distributions documentation](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Comment: Where can I find that `gradle.wrapper.properties` file? Thanks

Comment: should be in **app-folder/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem. For some reason I had the older version `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

Comment: After I changed the gradle version to your suggestion it gives me another error: Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

Comment: Why does this help though? React-Native uses gradle-2.14.1 by default when you init a new application, so why do we need a different one?

Comment: getting this error after adding this 
   > javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Comment: @DinIslamMilon - see this answer for an in-depth discussion of what you're seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/43574427#43574427.  I had it go away when I either 1. switched my default system JDK to 8 or earlier OR 2. upgrade to gradle 4.9

Comment: > Update your distributionUrl to the following

I had already told the wrapper to upgrade itself, so the URL was already set.  react-native is still failing when invoking ./gradlew commands inside my app folder.

Comment: You need to use latest version of Gradle. For example, to support Java 11, you can use `gradle-4.10-all.zip`

Comment: I then had to update my build.gradle as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709282/cannot-add-task-wrapper-as-a-task-with-that-name-already-exists

Answer (score 25):

Really the fastest way to get around this error is to use JDK 8. Except when you really need to use JDK9.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Don't forget to change your enviroment variable JAVA_HOME to the new JDK version!

Comment: related link to switch java version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you have `JDK8` installed and then set `JAVA_HOME` into `JDK8`

for example:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
```

or use `.bash_*` files to set this variable

Comment: I had this in my .zshrc on mac:  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Changing it to `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` picks the latest installed version of Java v8, and fixed this same issue.

Answer (score 8):

```bash
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add the following lines:

```bash
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

Now source the file to make the above changes effective in the current shell:

```bash
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: This last line `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` solved things for me - Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

On MacOS, I ran the following commands:

```bash
brew cask uninstall java
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8 "or just brew cask install java to install latest version"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error, but for a more recent version of Java - 10.0.2.

To fix my error, I followed the steps mentioned by `@Blacktoviche` in this Github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17688

When I opened the `android` folder inside my project via Android Studio, I was prompted with `Android Gradle plugin update recommended`. At the time, I was following a slightly outdated tutorial that told me to click `Don't remind me again for this project`.

However, as `@Blacktoviche` recommended in the github issue linked above, sometimes it's necessary to update the Gradle plugin. After updating, I also had to click `Install Build Tools 27... and sync project` (I don't remember the exact version).

After I followed these steps, I was able to successfully run my react native app on the Android Studio emulator.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

---- December 2018 --- keep attention ---
React Native does not work with Java versions higher than 8, so you need to uninstall your `9.0.1` version. To do so, execute the following commands:

```bash
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
ls -l
```

Identify the folder containing your Java Version, then remove it

```bash
sudo rm -rf jdk.x.x_xxx.jdk
```

After that you can download and install java 8 from oracle again. Refer to [jdk8 download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: "React Native does not work with Java versions higher than 8" absolutely incorrect. I have a build running off JDK 13 right now.

Comment: My answer is from DEC 2018. Get React Native from 2018, and then run on a JDK 13 and then if it works come here and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, you should run these command lines in the terminal:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows; Make sure you add your jdk path to the Environment path variable. 
Then open your android folder from your react native project into android studio. It will update necessary things for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when I forget to build the project using Android Studio. A simple sync and upgrading Gradle will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by downgrading my JDK to 8.