# Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE

Tags: android, react-native, java-9

I am trying to run my react-native app on Android simulator using terminal. I am using command

```
react-native run-android
```

Then I am getting error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I have already updated Java version and set JAVA_HOME too.

Comment: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1', looks like it does not have have support to run on JDK 9 yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native error: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867399/react-native-error-could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1)