# Could not able to run android with a react native application

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am working on a react native application and this is my my first project in react native. I have installed react native, jdk,  android studio, done the set up for AVD manager and emulator running also. But when I started to run the app through command line it showing me error Could not install the app on the device.

Can please anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native error: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867399/react-native-error-could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java version is 11.try to downgrade or install jdk version 8.

Comment: Thanks Yazdan Asadi, its working now. Actually there was unexpectedly both the versions of jdk. I just removed uninstalled the version 11 and my problem resolved. Thanks again and +1