# Could not determine java version from '12.0.2'

Tags: react-native, gradle

I followed this [React Native error: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867399/react-native-error-could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1) and changed to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip
```

in **PROJECT_PATH/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

but this didn't slved my problem it showed me new error  Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Support for JDK 12 was added in [Gradle 5.4](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4/release-notes.html#support-for-jdk12) so you need to update accordingly. The latest version however is 5.5.1 if you would prefer that. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2/54359875#54359875) elaborates more on this.