# Update Gradle in an existing java servlet jsp project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, netbeans, build.gradle

First a little background. I can go from netbeans 8.0 to 12 and open an existing older project that was built with netbeans native builder (pretty sure it's ant), do a clean and build, and the project runs perfect with zero problems.  You can totally be unaware of build.

Now the problem, gradle. I did my first gradle project, all was good, ran fine. Then a few days later netbeans informed me there was an update to gradle, I updated, restarted the ide, and nothing. The project would not build anymore, etc.

How, and I plea for help here, how do you make it so you can update gradle, and just press on with a clean and build?
Meaning, I want to be unaware that gradle even exist, I should not have to spend time fixing a build tool, I should be able to update, and forget I’m even using it. Any help is appreciated.

Been using netbeans for years, and never encountered such a mess.
Also if it's not possible in netbeans, I'll use eclipse, but I'd like to not even think about the build tool just like in the past. Any hints, tips?

Or after an update to gradle, is there some little thing that needs to be done?
I have used native build for years, mostly netbeans and some in eclipse and never needed to read one word of the ant documentation, it just always works.

Comment: [1] Is the **Groovy** plugin installed? To find out: **Tools > Plugins**, then click the **Installed** tab. Verify that the **Active** icon is green. [2] What versions of Java and Gradle are you using? [3] Verify that you can create a trivial new Gradle project on NB 12 using **File > New Project > Java with Gradle > Java Application**. [4] Go to **Tools > Options > Java**, then click the **Gradle** tab to verify that your setup looks correct, [5] As a workaround have you considered migrating your project to Maven? That doesn't address your problem at all, but it is a viable alternative.

Comment: @skomisa thanks.  Yes I can create a gradle project, it runs fine. The problem is if I updade gradle in netbeans the project is ruined.  Won't build, clean nothing. I figured if I update gradle, I could just restart the ide, do a fresh clean and build and be good to go..  I tried maven a while back, it was loading something for over 30 minutes, so I am not sure about maven.  I am new to both, I always just built with the tool that comes with netbeans. But now seems you are forced to use gradle if using spring.  The project wasn't spring, was servlet / jsp.

Comment: Also is there a way to use maven without that 30 minutes of loading whatever it loads?  I will check and make sure I have groovy, not at that computer now.

Comment: [1] Please update your question to specify your versions of Java and Gradle? Perhaps there is an incompatibility. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359875/2985643) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57228777/2985643) for more information. [2] The Maven load problem is a separate issue. It should be raised a separate question. [3] Make sure that Groovy/Gradle plugin is installed and activated with NB 12 before building your migrated project. [4] What is the actual error you get when you build that project? You need to provide a bit more detail than _"Won't build"_.