# Switch between different Python versions in Windows 10 cmd

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I don't like the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868600/6735815). 
because it involves renaming python executables.

Comment: Please make this into a question with details (such as restrictions and specific goals).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my discoveries.

Step 1. Go to [System Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYnxM.png). Click on `Environment Variables`

Step 2. Add new variables, such as [PYTHON_27_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKiZt.png)

- `PYTHON_27_HOME`:`%ProgramFiles%\Python27\`
- `PYTHON_36_HOME`:`%ProgramFiles%\Python36\`
- `PYTHON_HOME`:`%PYTHON_27_HOME%`

In my case, `PYTHON_27_HOME`(Python 2.7) is pointing to `C:\Program Files\Python27\`. You can replace this with your own path to `python`. `%PYTHON_HOME%` has a default value pointing to `%PYTHON_27_HOME%`, which is the path for Python 2.7. That's my preference, feel free to adjust accordingly. Be aware that there're 32-bit and 64-bit python. **Please use `%PROGRAMFILES%` for path to `C:\Program Files` and `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` for path to `C:\Program Files (x86)`.**

Step 3. Select `PATH` and click on `Edit`. [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqLek.png)

Step 4. Click on `New` and add [%PYTHON_HOME%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIdtZ.png). `%PYTHON_HOME%` will be added to `PATH` automatically every time you launch a command prompt.

---

In order to switch between different versions of python in cmd, here's the trick.

Step 5. I created a batch file with

```
@echo off
:: Switch Python version
DOSKEY python27=SET PATH=%PYTHON_27_HOME%;%PATH%
DOSKEY python36=SET PATH=%PYTHON_36_HOME%;%PATH%
```

Basically, it disables echo and creates two alias. In batch file any string after `::` is the comments. Every time, `python27` or `python36` is called, it re-exports %PATH% with the new Python path. Save it as `profile.bat`. You can name it whatever you want.

Step 6. 
Search for `regedit` (Registry Editor). Click on `Edit` > `New` > `String Value`. Give `AutoRun` as the `Value name` and `%USERPROFILE%\profile.bat` as the `Value data`. Here, please put your actual path value to the `profile.bat` we just created. So, whenever a command prompt is opened, it automatically loads `profile.bat`, which creates those two alias in the script.

Step 7. Close any command prompt you're using or just open a new command prompt. This is because your changes will not affect opened cmd window. Environment changes only happens to new CMD.

Step 8. Verify your results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZZ0p.png).

If you're using different Java versions, same trick applies, too. Find my `javac` environment setting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469319/6735815).

Comment: Wow!  That seems extremely convoluted and complicated.  Doesn't Windows support version managers, like asdf or pyenv?

Comment: It's just a taste and preference. I don't refer to use third party version manager.

Comment: windows has a `py` frontend which can run python 2 or python 3 depending on the shebang. Even if this solution above works, don't expect anyone to follow that in an industrial scale...

Comment: Windows has a py frontend? Any references to this py frontend thing appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to support various versions of Python, as well as other languages, is the asdf version manager.  It allows you to set a version of Python globally, as well as in each project folder.  This means that you can set your Python version to dynamically change based upon the folder you're working in.

[asdf version manager](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)

I haven't used Windows for almost 20 years, but I've heard that Windows 10 sports an Ubuntu-based subsystem for Linux.  I don't know if asdf will work with that, but it is worth a try.  Just use the instructions for setting asdf up with bash.

Comment: The question was specifically about Windows, which asdf doesn't support.

Comment: @looeee - First of all, I clearly addressed that fact in my post.  Secondly, it does indeed work if you enable WSL.  If you're the one who down-voted me, I would greatly appreciate it if you would reverse that action, since what I said is accurate and does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Use a symbolic link to youre current version and put that on your path instead.

Linux has the alternatives command to switch versions globally, but I do this:

1. Install Python variants under `C:\Python\Python38`, `C:\Python\Python36` etc
2. Set your PATH to include `C:\Python\Current;C:\Python\Current\Scripts`
3. Have a batch file like this to switch versions:

```
    @echo off
    echo 1. Python 3.8
    echo 2. Python 3.6   
    set /p ver="Enter Version: "
    
    if [%ver%]==[1] (
        SET FOLDER=C:\Python\Python38
    ) ELSE if [%ver%]==[2] (
        SET FOLDER=C:\Python\Python36
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO end
    )
    
    if exist C:\Python\Current\nul (
        rmdir C:\Python\Current
    )
    
    MKLINK /D C:\Python\Current %FOLDER%
    
    :end
```

The only downside is that MKLINK (and hence the batch file) requires elevated privilages