# Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3 - http error 503 in browser

Tags: jetty, apache-zeppelin

Following the minimalist installation instructions from [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/install.html), then on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 executing:

```
bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

The daemon starts OK, but pointing any browser to `http://localhost:8080` yields

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
    Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

The same thing happens if I run as root, or if I run the browser as root, or if I install via homebrew (`brew install apache-zeppelin`).

Permissions problem?

What is a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the same Zeppelin error after upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. It turned out Oracle JDK 8 had been blatted with openjdk. Reinstalling Oracle JDK 8 fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround was:

1. Install Java ***8***, following [How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x), i.e.

   ```
   brew tap caskroom/versions
   brew cask install java8
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
   sudo bash
   zeppelin-daemon.sh start
   /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
   ```
3. Point browser to:
       `http://localhost:8080`

Success! Conclusions:

1. Zeppelin 0.7.3 only supports Java <= 8.0
2. zeppelin-daemon.sh must be run as root, but browser doesn't have to be

Comment: macOS 10.13.3, Zeppelin 0.7.3. Unfortunately your workaround does not work for me.

Comment: @thenaturalist Thanks for the info - in the absence of any other input here, is the only different between our setups 10.13.1 vs 10.13.3 then?

Comment: @jitz2 not sure what led to the hickup. Initially seemed so. Completely deleted Java off my machine and installed again after reboot & followed the steps you described and now it works. In any case props to you for figuring out Java 8 & root!

Comment: I had a same error code with Zeppelin. After installing Java 1.8 with Brew and setting java home like above, I re-installed Zeppelin but with brew as `brew install apache-zeppelin` . Now it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Java 1.8 as mentioned in the above post.
2. If we can give the super user password at the time of installing, we do not have to run as root every time. See below for the logs and the option to give password.

   ```
   [ksurendranath@machine /usr/local/Cellar/apache-zeppelin/0.7.3/libexec/logs 10:54 AM ]$ brew cask install java8
   ==> Tapping caskroom/cask
   Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask'...
   remote: Counting objects: 4057, done.
   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4022/4022), done.
   remote: Total 4057 (delta 37), reused 824 (delta 31), pack-reused 0
   Receiving objects: 100% (4057/4057), 1.39 MiB | 11.49 MiB/s, done.
   Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), done.
   Tapped 0 formulae (4,066 files, 4.4MB)
   ==> Creating Caskroom at /usr/local/Caskroom
   ==> We'll set permissions properly so we won't need sudo in the future
   ```

   Password:

Answer (score -1):

Get the process info on the port you are using the Zeppelin server

1)sudo netstat -anp|grep 8080

2)sudo kill (ProcessID)

3)/zeppelin-server/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh restart

This might help you

Comment: Well, does it help..? :)

Comment: yeah definitely do that

Comment: I think you are just saying there might be a port collision. That wasn't the problem though - see other answers.

Comment: uh:( come-on; if you see in the logs there might be Exception .name them

Comment: Sorry for being mean