# Monkeyrunner issue

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

When I execute monkeyrunner I get this:

> supers-MacBook-Pro:android-testing manuel$ monkeyrunner
>
> -Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/super/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib:/Users/super/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64 is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I searched info but I haven't found it. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem, I changed java 10 to java 8 in bash_profile, I was working with an unsupported version.

### UPDATE:

Although I got MonkeyRunner to run, I had the same issue after a while. I solved definitely it changing the extension of Info.plist located in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents to Info.plist.disabled, so macOS system discards this jdk version, and chooses the next  higher version, in my case, jdk 1.8.0_45. For more info, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x).