# how can I replace java 10.0.1 to java 1.8.0

Tags: java-8, java-10

```
    /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_181, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have installed java 8 also but still its showing me java 10

I have tried [How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x) 
but not working for me.

Comment: "Not working" isnt a working problem description. Do the commands not work, are they simply not giving any results, ...

Comment: What operating systeam you using?

Comment: *but still its showing me java 10*... where/how?

Comment: by default it always picking up 10, I want to use java8

Comment: I am using mac OS 10.13.6

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_181
> 
>

Comment: A good tool to handle multiple versions of java is sdkman.  install sdkman then type `sdk list java` and you can install multiple versions similar to NVM.

Answer (score 1):

In your bash config, have something as below:

```
##-- Switch between JDK 8 & 9
export ORIG_PATH=$PATH
export JAVA8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export JAVA10_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 10.0.1)

##-- Default Java 8
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA8_HOME
export ORIG_PATH=$PATH

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In this way, you'll have default Java8 while still having Java10 on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted java 10 using 
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
using https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

And later delete java 10 folder

now check again java 8 is available if not install 8