# My Java Runtime Environment isn't updating

Tags: java, terminal

I tried updating to the latest version of JRE and I checked my Java Control Panel and it says I have the latest version. But when I go on my terminal and checked by typing

> java -version

I'm getting

> java version "1.6.0_65"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)

However, when I checked the version by typing

> /Library/Internet\
>   Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version

I did get the correct version:

> java version "1.8.0_181"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)

What can I do to make sure I am running version 1.8? I need it to run elasticsearch and I've been pulling my hair out over the right version of java on my machine (Mac).

Comment: If you are using window, check your path settings.  It may still pointing to 1.6.  Also check java_home making sure it is pointing to the latest version

Comment: @Jules I'm on Mac

Comment: Check this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x

Comment: @Jules Ah I see. But when I ran /usr/libexec/java_home -V the 1.8 version isn't showing up as a Matching Java Virtual Machine. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, Can't help you with a specific question as I am a window user :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run this code

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System.
2. Click on Advance System Settings
3. Under Advance Tab, click on "Environmental Variables"
4. Under System Variable section check "path".

check under path what is set for java.

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variable path, it would be pointing to the earlier version
Update that path and again check. It should work

Comment: when I ran /usr/libexec/java_home -V the 1.8 version isn't showing up as a Matching Java Virtual Machine. Any idea why? I do see two versions of 1.6 listed but not the 1.8

Comment: is there a way you can uninstall the earlier version? I am a windows user, so  I am not sure if it's possible in mac

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I need to download the entire Java Development Kit