# switch java version on mac OS

Tags: java, macos

Im trying to switch the java version with the following

`export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_172'`

but when I run `java -version` I got the following

`java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)`

I want to switch to the `1.8.0_172` version in MAC how it can be done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x)

Comment: @lakshman It looks like the OP is already trying to apply the solutions of that question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: No He doesn't. OP uses quotes instead of backticks and there are other answers as well.

Comment: @lakshman I said trying, and most other answers there are variations on that theme. I think it would have been helpful to point out that mistake initially (as it is non-obvious to people not familiar with bash).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have jdk1.8.0.172 installed, one option is:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: to see the java versions you have available:
`ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest for me was using [jenv](https://www.jenv.be/)

It is similar to rvm or nvm to easily switch between java versions.

## Steps:

`brew install jenv`

Bash

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Zsh

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

`echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc`

In the terminal run `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`
(This is a precautionary measure in case you have output that breaks the text parsing. In my case this did make a difference)

`jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home`

**jdk1.8.0_231.jdk** -> Use whatever version you have on your machine.

Then use `javac -version`to verify it has been changed.

Comment: Thank you. I found this solution to be much more robust for future-proofing.

Answer (score 4):

The above worked for me (removing quotes) with Mac OS Catalina, however I also had to set the path variable like below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{java version.jdk}/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Where {java_version.jdk} was any of the Java version listed after running

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

The above command will give you all java versions installed in your system.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v <VERSION YOU WANT TO USE FROM ABOVE LIST`>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Install all the java version you want on your mac, reference: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

```
~ % ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk-1.8.jdk jdk-11.jdk  jdk-17.jdk  jdk-21.jdk
```

2.Check all the Java version you've installed

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

3.Set up `.zshenv`

```
  alias j8="export JAVA_HOME=`(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)`; java -version"
  alias j11="export JAVA_HOME=`(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)`; java -version"
  alias j17="export JAVA_HOME=`(/usr/libexec/java_home -v17)`; java -version"
  alias j21="export JAVA_HOME=`(/usr/libexec/java_home -v21)`; java -version"
```

4.Set default JDK version globally on `.zshrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.xxxx)`
```

5.Finally, you can switch JDK version by `j**`

```
~ % j8
java version "1.8.0_391"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_391-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.391-b13, mixed mode)
```