# Not able to switch the Java version to Java 17

Tags: java, macos, java-17, corretto, jenv

Posting again since someone moved my question a community where there is not much activity and the solution provided there [in the comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1691128/not-able-to-switch-java-version-to-java-17?noredirect=1#comment2599976_1691128) did not work.

I have installed Amazon Corretto Java 17 from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/downloads-list.html).

However, I am not able to switch the Java version to Java 17.

Following are the steps I have already tried:

1.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(`/usr/libexec/java_home -v17`)
```

2. `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. I have also check the highest version of Java using below command:
   `/usr/libexec/java_home` and it shows correct Java 17 version:
   `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home`
4. I have also checked all the versions of Java installed on my machine using command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and it correctly shows Java 8, 11, and 17:

```
17.0.1 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 17" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home

11.0.9.1 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 11" /Users/harsh.pamnani/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.9.1/Contents/Home

1.8.0_275 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

5. I also added `JAVA_HOME` exports mentioned in `step-1` and `step-2` to `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` as well.
6. I have followed multiple questions on StackOverflow and multiple
   blogs as well. For example,

[How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos)

[switch java version on mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611522/switch-java-version-on-mac-os)

https://java.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-switch-java-version-on-mac

https://www.lotharschulz.info/2019/08/21/mac-change-default-java-version

https://akrabat.com/using-jenv-to-select-java-version-on-macos/

https://www.happycoders.eu/java/how-to-switch-multiple-java-versions-windows/

7. I am using `jenv` to switch between different java versions. Even `jenv` is not able to find Java 17. I used `jenv versions` and following is the output:

```
system
  1.8
  1.8.0.275
  11
  11.0
* 11.0.9.1 (set by /Users/harsh.pamnani/.jenv/version)
  corretto64-1.8.0.275
  corretto64-11.0.9.1
```

8. I have also checked that `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `Java 17`. Here is the screenshot: [Screenshot](https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuEGxB8)

Even after following all the steps above when I do `java --version`, it is still set to Java 11:

```
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS, mixed mode)
```

9. I have also checked `PATH` variable, and nothing seems to be relatable to Java. Following is the output for path variables:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/harsh.pamnani/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
```

Could someone please help me understand if I am missing anything here. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to switch between versions of Java, back and forth? Or do you just want to use Java 17 only, and dump Java 11?

Comment: I need to switch between different java versions, because some of my projects are on Java 11 and some of the projects are on Java 17.

Comment: Java is backward compatible. In other words Java 17 can run code that was compiled with JDK 11. Hence I don't think you need to switch between 11 and 17.

Comment: I know that. But, the reverse is not possible. i.e. `Java 11` can not run `Java 17` code. And as I have asked in my question above, my current java version is set to `Java 11`. So, if I am running any `Java 17` project, the compilation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which java` is often used to find the exact executable you are calling when you type in `java`.

Keep in mind that when you type in the command `java` your JAVA_HOME setting is not used.  Rather, the operating system `PATH` setting is used.  If you have an older copy of java "before" the one you want to use on the path, then that's what the operating system will give you.  To fix a problem like this, you need to alter your path such that the directory of your desired java version comes before any other java versions.

I do see that you checked your `PATH` setting, but I think you didn't know what to check, because you only listed directories.  In those directories, a `java` executable exists.  If the old executable comes in a directory earlier in the path, that's the version of java you will get when running it from the command line, regardless of any other settings.

Now, it is still important to have the JAVA_HOME set correctly, because when various Java tools want to discover items, thy might read JAVA_HOME (and if it is wrong, get directed to a non-matching JVM).

Comment: Thanks a lot Edwin for the reply. I have checked all the directories under PATH as suggested by you. Only `/usr/bin` seems to have the `java` executable. And there is only one executable for `java`. Attaching a screenshot for you. https://share.getcloudapp.com/6quvgRrR  Could you please help me understand how to identify whether this executable is for `java 11`. And if it is for `java 11`, how can I point it to `java 17`. Again, thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: @harshpamnani if you run `/usr/bin/java -version` it will tell you what version it is.  Believe that number, as that's the only version that file will ever report (even if it is moved).  If you need a different version, you have to find a different `java` executable file, and put it earlier in your path than the ones you don't want.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. I found out what the issue is. When I did `/usr/bin/java -version`, it showed correct `Java 17` version. However, when I did `which java`, it was showing `/Users/harsh.pamnani/.jenv/shims/java`. I found the java version for that and it is pointing to `Java 11`. Attaching a screenshot https://share.getcloudapp.com/NQu7PbnE. I will raise the concern with `jenv` that it is not able to correctly identify `Java 17` (maybe they don't have support for that yet since it is new). Thanks a lot Edwin. You have been a great help.

Comment: @harshpamnani Until you get your answer from `jenv` (which I tend to just not use, as it is more trouble than it is worth, and it is not part of "standard" java installations), you can just put a new PATH entry before this .jenv/shims entry (or better yet, remove the .jenv/shims entry.  Personally the idea of installing a program to set a two environmental variables (PATH and JAVA_HOME) just sounds beyond silly to me.  Just edit your ~/.bashrc (or equivalent) if you need per-user overrides.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. I removed `export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"` from my `.zshrc` file and now it is working. `java -version` correctly points to `Java -17`. The only reason I like to use `jenv` is because, I find it handy when the the different projects are running different java versions, we can use `jenv local`, and it will change the java version just for that project and not the global version. In this way, I don't have to change java versions everytime I switch projects.

Comment: @harshpamnani Well, if something needs a specific Java, I typically configure the IDE to reference it (if in development) or the shell script wrapper to have an explicit entry (as well as export the entry to the environment).  If your program gets really big and fancy, you can even put that value in a conf file.  That way you don't have to reconfigure your environment to match what you are working on, as each executable now has it's own configuration.

Comment: That would be awesome. I will try that. Thanks a lot Edwin. Much appreciated.