# google app engine project not running in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am developing a project with Google App Engine in Eclipse. Three days ago, everything worked fine.
But I do not what I do but now I cant to run project in debug mode in local host.

When I run it I get the following error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory (file:/Users/gallavie/Library/Application%20Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar) to method java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create a DevAppServer
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:301)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:383)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:354)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.SocksSocketImpl.<init>()
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevSocketImplFactory.<clinit>(DevSocketImplFactory.java:76)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.SocksSocketImpl.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevSocketImplFactory.<clinit>(DevSocketImplFactory.java:72)
    ... 12 more
```

How can I fix this?

thank you for replay 
when i downgrade to java 12 to java 8 i get this error

```js
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory (file:/Users/gallavie/Library/Application%20Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar) to method java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Dec 14, 2019 7:34:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value '/Users/gallavie/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/config/sdk/logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspaces/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/Darimpo/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
 at java.base/java.util.Properties.put(Properties.java:1316)
 at java.base/java.util.Collections$CheckedMap.put(Collections.java:3638)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.setTimeZone(SharedMain.java:183)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.postServerActions(SharedMain.java:152)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:398)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are using Google App Engine in a version that does not work with Java 13**.

The root cause is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.SocksSocketImpl.<init>()
```

This means **`java.net.SocksSocketImp`** exists but **does not have a default constructor** (constructor without parameters). The Google App Engine (`com.google.appengine.tools.development`) was compiled with `java.net.SocksSocketImp` with default constructor, but is now executed with `java.net.SocksSocketImp` without default constructor. In Java 12 and lower the system library contains `java.net.SocksSocketImp` with default constructor, but **in Java 13 `java.net.SocksSocketImp` has no default constructor anymore**.

Comment: thank you for replay i edited my question I get other error when i downgrade java version

Comment: @user2320349 It seems you run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55694942/6505250) which is similar but different. Probably, you have to use Java 8 or better use a newer Google App Engine version, if there is one.

Comment: thank you thank you i use java 8 and is work you save my week