# How do I change the default Spark_home and Java_home in SparklyR? (R Mac OS)

Tags: r, macos, apache-spark, sparklyr, java-home

1. I've installed Spark inside a folder in my home directory and added that to my .bash_profile. From the terminal, I can run `pyspark` or `spark-shell` after `source ~/.bash_profile`. But for Sparklyr, the default spark location is inside the user folder. Is there a way to permanently change the default location or setting up a path variable without having to configure it everytime I run a new R session?
2. When I try to connect  spark declaring the location spark is installed, I get the following error message:

`sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = "~/server/spark/")`

`Error: Java 11 is only supported for Spark 3.0.0+

Is there a way to permanently configure java_home for sparklyr as well? I haven't found anything about this in the documentation.

Thanks!

I'm using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4, RStudio Version 1.2.5033, Spark version 2.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using two steps:

1. I got the appropriate Java home by running `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` in the terminal (this should also already be set in the bash profile, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x))
2. I added a JAVA_HOME (and SPARK_HOME) variable to my .Renviron file so that I wouldn't have to set it for each session.  I used `usethis::edit_r_environ()` to open the file and restarted my R session for it to take effect.  (More details on .Renviron generally [here](https://rstats.wtf/r-startup.html#renviron)).