# How to install-run Cytoscape v3.8.0 on OSX doesn't run

Tags: macos, java-11, cytoscape

I have a problem with latest version of Cytoscape 3.8.0 It doesnt start. I can see only logo and than nothing. Computer is running OSX 10.13.6. I am using successfully version Cytoscape 3.7.2 but I want to upgrade. When I run script mac.sh I got following:

```
Target Cytoscape version: 3.8.0
```

Your shell is bash
Compatible OS version found: 10.13

- Pass: OS Version = 10.13.6
- Pass: Following Oracle JDK found:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk
Fail: Java is not reachable.
Try re-installing Java 11.

I can confirm that java is in place /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and versions jdk-11.0.7.jdk   jdk-12.0.2.jdk  jdk-14.0.1.jdk

I guess that version 37 and 38 work with java 11? I have reinstalled java 11 with same results as before. Version 38 doesnt start. When I try to start version 38 from terminal with cytoscape.sh I got long error message which starts with:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
```

karaf.base: /Applications/Cytoscape_v3.8.0/framework
JAVA_HOME: null
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.dto;version="1.0",org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",org.osgi.resource.dto;version="1.0...
I can paste whole error message if needed.

Any idea what should i do? Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape 3.7.x requires Java 8.  Cytoscape 3.8.0 requires Java 11. It looks like your java home is incorrect.  If you do:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

it should point to your java 11 installation.  On my mac it says:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Note that the "/Contents/Home" is important.  To set your actual JAVA_HOME, do

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. What Scooter Morris mentioned is correct, but I had to follow an [additional link on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x) to get it fixed.

**This is exactly what I did:**
In my case I had to run:`/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see the Java Virtual Machines I have installed and specify the V 11 using:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.7`
```

Then running the `./mac.sh` command tells me everything checks out and Cytoscape can finnaly run :)

Edit: I should add that I can only run cytoscape by launching it from the terminal via:

```
cd /Applications/Cytoscape_v3.8.0
./cytoscape.sh
```

Clicking the app icon only results in the app crashing on load but it appears to work fine by launching it from the script. I don't have this issue on Mac OS 10.14 so maybe its a software version issue or some background app in my computer is getting in the way of launching the app normally.