# How to get MacOS (Catalina) to use custom Java version?

Tags: java, macos, java-11, macos-catalina

I am trying to change the default Java version on my machine from version 15 (i.e. openjdk 15.0.1) to version 11 (i.e. openjdk version 11.0.2). I have followed various solutions provided online, but at the end of the day, I just want the following result:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.9 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But instead, I get:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Most solutions that I've found, suggest setting a new value to my `JAVA HOME` environmental variable (both in-line and in `.bash_profile`), where as of now, I have as:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Even removing `jdk-15.0.1.jdk` entirely from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` didn't seem to change anything. So, this JDK must be defined and used somewhere else, and its existance is overriding anything I put in my `.bash_profile` file. Has anyone else experienced this before? Is this change possible?

Comment: Also, if the first answer in that linked question doesn't help you, the second may.

Comment: Sorry.  Here's that reference again...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x

Comment: Not an official answer, but [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue was within my `.bash_profile`. While I'm not sure if this is the case for everyone, my `PATH` environment variable settings superseded my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, and my `PATH` variable had reference my `JAVA_HOME` variable inside it. This was resolved by changing the following in my `.bash_profile` file.

If `JAVA_HOME` is the only variable added, then the following should work.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

If there are others then this should work.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home

export SOME_OTHER_PATH=/somepath

export PATH=$SOME_OTHER_PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the *first* line in your `.bash_profile` file that talks about `JAVA_HOME` is this:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.9)
```

---

You can run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see a list of all your installed Java Virtual Machines. On my machine, I have the following (mine will look slightly different because this output is from Big Sur):

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (6):
    15.0.1 (x86_64) "UNDEFINED" - "OpenJDK 15.0.1" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.9 (x86_64) "UNDEFINED" - "OpenJDK 11.0.9" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.9/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.6 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_275 (x86_64) "UNDEFINED" - "OpenJDK 8" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+275/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_131 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+275/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The line at the very bottom (which may not exist in Catalina, but which you can get by running `/usr/libexec/java_home` is your currently selected JVM.

Comment: But this just sets JAVA_HOME, RIGHT?  The OP said they tried that, and it didn't change anything...if I'm reading correctly.

Comment: @Steve yes, it does. I suspect that the issue is still with `$JAVA_HOME` (having dealt with a lot of problems with it myself), unless I'm misunderstanding the question, in which case the question you linked seems like the best bet.

Comment: Hi @Sam, this is the very first line in my `.bash_profile` already. I've tried quick a few solutions, but I'm not sure what is happening. It almost seems as though it is ignoring the file altogether.

Comment: @ChloeBennett OK, just to make sure the file works, add the line `echo "Profile Test"` to your `.bash_profile` and then open a new shell/source your profile. "Profile Test" should be printed right above your prompt. Does that work?

Comment: That said, I've found the issue, and I don't think I would have noticed it without this thread. It turns out that my overarching PATH variable (which was initially using my JAVA_HOME variable, had been overwriting by my android settings). So, my system was reading PATH, but not JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @ChloeBennett Good to hear!