# How to brew install java?

Tags: java, macos, homebrew

I'd like to setup java on a new OS X machine, and prefer to use brew for OS X package management. How can I install latest java using brew?

Comment: If you want openjdk: `brew install openjdk` [https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk)

Answer (score 544, accepted):

Turns out `java` has been moved into brew core recently, so the correct command as of August 2022 is:

```bash
brew install java
```

Then check your installation by running

```bash
java -version
```

If the result does *not* looks like this:

```
openjdk 18.0.2 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 18.0.2+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 18.0.2+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

but like this:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Then you also need to create a symlink for the system Java wrappers to find this JDK:

```bash
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk \
     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Comment: How can I install an older java version?

Comment: Oh, this is a good question @kikulikov, maybe try this, ymmv: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk

Comment: when I do `brew install java` I get `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "java".
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.`  (preceded by `These similarly named formulae were found:
app-engine-java...`)

Comment: @Sigfried are you on the latest version of brew?

Comment: @TimFulmer I think I am now. I managed to fix whatever problem is was that triggered that 3-day episode of yak shaving. It eventually involved reinstalling brew, ruby, rvm, java, possibly xcode, and every executable file on my computer with an odd number of bytes. Thanks for asking! :)

Comment: Haha @Sigfried! Yes, the wipe everything approach. Been there, done that plenty. Personally, I use `brew` for system packages (sometimes java), `nvm` for node, and for python please please be very careful to use proper virtual environments. Modifying the system python on any distro has never gone well for me.

Comment: And don't overlook to create a symlink: `For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk` :)

Comment: Thanks for the symlink comment @bathyscapher. This was missing from the question and is an essential step (I had installed openjdk but still got an error). I've edited the question to add the symlink.

Comment: Instead of /opt/homebrew I had to do symlink to directory in /usr/local/opt and the way I was able to get the correct location was to run `brew info openjdk` and run the command after 'For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with' which in my case was `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: On my Mac running Big Sur, I had to do: sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.2.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk \ 
     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

Comment: I had to `source ~/.zshrc` after symlinking

Comment: You can easily find the symlink by running 
`brew info openjdk@your-java-version`
and your symlink will be specified in the response

Comment: If you are skeptical of the idea of need for `sudo ln`, the command is given after the installation of the package from `brew`. You can see this recommendation by running `brew info java`/`brew info openjdk`.

Comment: For the symlink I had to do following: sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk. Double check with "brew info java" which symlink you have to trigger

Comment: @ElijahLofgren info of `brew info openjdk` provided me the same solution as the post. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ```sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk \
     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk``` worked for me

Comment: I had to use the sudo command on MacOs M2 Sonoma and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 100):

As an add-on to the accepted answer: to install a certain version of Java, e.g. version 11, run:

```
brew install openjdk@11
```

And symlink it:

```
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk \
     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```

Comment: java -version returns 8 but 11 is installed.

Comment: Are you sure the installation of java 11 was successful?

Comment: Perhaps you installed java from java.com prior to this? If so follow the instructions found here to remove it. 
https://www.java.com/en/uninstall/uninstall_instructions.html#macOS
for macos use:
`sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java`

Comment: To symlink it, just use `brew link openjdk@11` instead.

Comment: The symlink command brew link openjdk@11 
Does not work

Answer (score 22):

I had to `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: `brew info java` shows the current command to run, this was the same for me too

Answer (score 15):

After multiple tries, here is a recipe that allows for me to switch between the different versions of OpenJDK and this approach appears to work on Ventura.

First, install all the necessary OpenJDK versions (for me I needed 8, 11, 17, and 20)

```
brew install openjdk@8
brew install openjdk@11
brew install openjdk@17
brew install openjdk@20
```

Update the wrapper, as recommended in the multiple postings: `sudo rm -f /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk` and `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`.

Update your `.zshrc` as follows

```
alias j8="export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8 ; java -version"
alias j11="export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11 ; java -version"
alias j17="export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17 ; java -version"
alias j20="export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@20 ; java -version"
```

To switch your version, run the alias `j8`, `j11`, etc.

Don't forget to prepend the `$PATH` in your `~/.zshrc` with `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"` otherwise the system java will have precedent.

Note that this approach is particularly useful because I rely on `brew` as my primary (and arguably most consistent) package manager.

Comment: As a new mac user (switching from Windows) trying to also set this up for the first time, I am not quite clear what you mean by : 

"Don't forget to prepend the $PATH in your ~/.zshrc with export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" otherwise the system java will have precedent."

I assume this is my issue because the alias is not switching to different Java versions like it should and I am not sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 9):

Assembled from the answers here and [How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos):

You can use brew to install multiple Java versions and run a command to switch between the versions as required.

**Example**

Install two Java versions (change Java versions as pleased):

```
brew install openjdk@19
brew install openjdk@8
```

Use the following command to see the installed versions:

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

you should see the two versions specified in the response (if not, read further to create a symlink). Now you can select the Java version using:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 8`
```

verify selected version:

```
java -version
```

you can further export the JAVA_HOME variable in your shell init file as specified in the attached SOF thread.

Now, in case you do not see the Java version in `/usr/libexec/java_home` as expected and the version selection of that missing version is not working, **you might need to add a symlink**:

Executing `brew info openjdk@the-missing-java-version`should return the location of the installed version and will specify a symlink command that you should run for the system to find the SDK. The response text look something similar to:

```
...For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk...
```

Comment: Great answer.  Was only by following your suggestions that I finally got all this to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

run

```
brew reinstall openjdk
```

and it will display the following which shows your file path:

```
    For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/gerarddonnelly/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"
```

I then ran the code below, which I took from the output above:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

The other issue I had was that Elasticsearch was not recognising my JAVA version. To fix that I added the following line to my .bash_profile

```
EXPORT JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

then I ran

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to refresh my profile.

After that it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Update for recent Homebrew builds: `sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install the Oracle version of java's SDK with homebrew, use the following command:

```
brew install --cask oracle-jdk
```

If you don't care, then use the accepted answer by @Tim Fulmer to get the OpenJDK version

`brew install java`

Answer (score 0):

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew update
brew install openjdk@19


sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? How does this differ from the other answers?

Comment: it is exact set of code that is required.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is stuck on Mac OS Monterey, installing Java 11 using the brew command is what worked for me. It might be similar for previous version (not too sure though).

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
```

Comment: Please explain how this is different and better wrt all the other answers. I don't see what is added here.

Answer (score -1):

```
acaibird: ~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines  brew info java
==> openjdk: stable 21.0.2 (bottled) [keg-only]
Development kit for the Java programming language
https://openjdk.java.net/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2 (600 files, 331.2MB)
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-01-28 at 21:25:54
From: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/git/homebrew/homebrew-core.git/Formula/o/openjdk.rb
License: GPL-2.0-only with Classpath-exception-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: giflib ✔, harfbuzz ✔, jpeg-turbo ✔, libpng ✔, little-cms2 ✔
==> Requirements
Build: Xcode (on macOS) ✔
Required: macOS >= 10.15 (or Linux) ✔
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include"
==> Analytics
install: 87,975 (30 days), 237,751 (90 days), 869,053 (365 days)
install-on-request: 48,996 (30 days), 131,628 (90 days), 506,308 (365 days)
build-error: 394 (30 days)
```

```bash
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).