# The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, apple-m1

I couldn't run the flutter app on android emulator or android phone. I installed the recently released android studio for arm-mac platform on m1 mac. Please answer if I am doing anything wrong here or is it the problem with the release itself.

Debug console output:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor -v output :

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /Users/hmnth/FlutterDev/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (10 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/hmnth/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    ✗ Could not determine java version

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at Applications/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Android Studio not found at Applications/Contents
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.107

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Comment: you are using windows? if yes then install jaba and add its bin folder in envoirment variable

Comment: Error is clear, do you have Java installed on your machine and set environment variables correctly?

Comment: You need to install `Java`, here's how to install `Java` with `homebrew`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601196/how-to-brew-install-java/70786302#70786302

Comment: After updating my Android Studio .I am facing this issues . I resolved it using o to Applications -> right click on Android Studio -> choose "Show Package Contents".

I have only folder .jbr (not have .jre). So, I create new folder with name .jre and copy folder "Contents" (from .jbr) -> paste to .jre folder.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to Applications then right click on Android Studio, then choose "Show Package Contents", create a new folder inside `jre` named `jdk` and copy the contents of `jre` to `jdk`

This is the link for the fix https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76215#issuecomment-864407892

Comment: Be sure to copy, not move.

Comment: you may also link : 

`cd jre`


`mkdir jdk`


`cd jdk`


`ln -sf ../Contents Contents`

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: Thanks, works for me, but I have "jbr" folder - "/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jbr" so I create new one - "/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre" and create "jdk" inside this new folder and copy content and restart, it's work for me,  does any one please let me know what is "jbr"?

Comment: After updating my Android Studio .I am facing this issues . I resolved it using o to Applications -> right click on Android Studio -> choose "Show Package Contents".

I have only folder .jbr (not have .jre). So, I create new folder with name .jre and copy folder "Contents" (from .jbr) to .jre folder. not move .

Comment: I don't have `jre` folder inside Contents

Answer (score 20):

In 2023.

Go to Applications -> right click on Android Studio -> choose "Show Package Contents".

I have only folder .jbr (not have .jre). So, I create new folder with name .jre and copy folder "Contents" (from .jbr) -> paste to .jre folder.

Open terminal and run: flutter doctor -v

That works for me.

Comment: may also create a soft link `ln -s "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr" "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre"`

Comment: Best answer for 2023

Comment: In my case  Go to Applications -> right click on Android Studio -> choose "Show Package Contents". -> Contents -> Create folder named jre (not .jre) -> copy Contents folder from jbr to our new folder jre

Comment: This one holds true for me with the latest Android Studio Hedgehog. on MacOS 14 with M2 chip.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue because I didn't have Java installed.  If you can't see a Java icon under System Preferences, Java 7 or later versions is not installed. [Link to java.com](https://www.java.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I've installed Java 8 and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

2022
First of all, check out did you install Java on your mac.
After that I suggest to install Java 19.
If you finish this step

on command pannel : nano .zshrc
add the below code to the  bottom of file;

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.daml/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

That is all.
You are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issues by doing the following, I sync my project with Gradle files

I downloaded Java 8 (but I don't think this guy did the work)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Following command if you have use homebrew,

```
brew install java
```

When java is installed, run the following command,

```
java --version
```

If the output is like this,

> openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.2)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)

Then you are good to go! Otherwise, run the following command to get going,

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```