# libpq-dev Unable to locate a Java Runtime

Tags: psycopg2, libpq

I used `sudo apt install libpq-dev python3-dev` to install [libpq-dev](https://pypi.org/project/libpq-dev/), but I got a puzzling error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

I read through the docs, and didn't see anything about a JRE, and people at work say I shouldn't need a JRE for this.

### ***Do I really need a JRE for libpq-dev?***

***If so, what version? If not, what am I doing wrong?***

Comment: Are you by any chance [using a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69508381/5320906)?

Comment: `libpq-dev` as you link to is a  PyPi package so you need to use `pip`. So `sudo pip install libpq-dev`.  Not sure where you are getting `python3-dev` from?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, I am using a mac.