# Unable to install or find python on terminal, Java error shows up when I try to install

Tags: python, java, installation, terminal

So I have tried to install python when my terminal showed that I didn't have python, which was weird because I thought I did. When I tried to find it I couldn't find it, I used commands like:

```
which python
```

When I tried to remove python (I was trying random things):

```
sudo apt remove python
```

Then this error would show:
**The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.**

When I tried installing it with

```
apt install python
```

It would then throw the same Java error.

UPDATE: Apologies, I am on macOS Monterrey! 12.4

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: [If you are on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508381/the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-unable-to-locate-a-java-runtime-that-suppor).

Answer (score 0):

The python is by default install in linux you can check with `which python3` or `which python2`.

Uninstalling python from your device is not a good idea, Your OS is depends on python, **If you uninstall default python from your device then your **system will be corrupted****, Your terminal , Firefox and etc system software are using resources from default python.

If your JRE is not configure then you can configure with https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre#2-installing-openjdk-jre officials.

---

If you need to run multiple python versions on your device then must go with pyenv it's safe and easy.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: Yeah honestly I am not sure when or how I might've deleted python from my Mac, but when I do the which python3 statement it now shows this:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3`

I guess better than python not being found like yesterday?

Comment: there are different versions in python, python2 and python3. 

when you do `which python` then it's looking for python2 by default.