# pyspark session is not working in pycharm

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I recently started using mac and there I have installed pyspark. Now whenever I try to create a SparkSession .

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
        .getOrCreate()
)
```

It throws me an error if I execute/debug it from pycharm although it works fine if i run the python program via terminal eg: python main.py.

The error it throws is:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
> head: illegal line count -- -1

> RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: it might be the case where pycharm doesn't know the path to the java executable.

Comment: I tried adding the java path using this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/switching-boot-jdk.html , but it didn't work.

Comment: You probably don't have Java installed on your system. If you want to install with brew, here's how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601196/how-to-brew-install-java/70786302#70786302

Comment: Java is installed