# Can't launch fresh React Native project. Been stuck for a while please help (Could not compile settings file settings.gradle)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, java-16

My SSD got screwed, so I had to start everything fresh. Now I'm stuck in setup. I followed React native environment setup step by step very carefully and before that I installed Java 16. Now when I try to launch fresh project I initialized this is what I get:

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\Alyz\Documents\testProj\android\settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\Alyz\Documents\testProj\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
...
```

Comment: Android studio wasnt respecting my java version in the project structure. needed to set the JAVA_HOME for it to use openjdk 8 like specified in the react-native environment-setup. I lost a week and hours of sleep before discovering this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

I just found a forum post saying that they do not support Java 16. After downgrading to Java 15 everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried `npm run android`. After removing the JDK 16 (which I have manually installed after downloading from Oracle) using the below commands

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java

cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines && rm -rf  jdk-16.0.1.jdk
```

and then installing JAVA 14 using `homebrew`

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk 
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk14
```

Answer (score -1):

Gradle does not support Java 16 yet.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: @StupidWolf The _"Gradle does not support JAVA 16 yet"_ looks like an answer to me, the link is just to support that answer.