# Setting JAVA_HOME in macos

Tags: java, macos

When I do

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`"
```

I get

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Which is a JRE and not the one I want - it's under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/...

Going into the .bash_profile file I see JAVA_HOME is set to

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

following the link - java_home is a file.

So not sure how the above works or how it got changed to the JRE instead of the JDK.

I suppose I can change the JAVA_HOME in the profile file to the one I want - but is there a preferred way of making sure the JDK is used by all apps on the mac.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/419705 <-- relevant

Comment: No program is "required" to use `JAVA_HOME`. Most will, but will fallback to the result of `which java`. In general, you want apps to use the JRE, not the JDK except for your IDEs