# Multiplatform error when building iosApp: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on a multiplatform app in Kotlin on Android Studio and when I try to run the app to an iOS simulator, I get this error:

The following build commands failed:

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Build\ shared /Users/cjm/AndroidStudioProjects/GlobeMultiplatform/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-882AF45D8B8C4938AC461F4FBA0FE197.sh (in target 'shared' from project 'Pods')

The code in the `build.gradle` that sets the cocoa pods is this:

```
cocoapods {
    summary = "Shared"
    homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
    ios.deploymentTarget = "13"
    frameworkName = "shared"
    podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
}
```

I ran pod install and it showed success but the build of the app still fails. How can I fix this error? What is causing this error? I am brand new to Kotlin and especially Kotlin Multiplatform so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

EDIT: Here's what Xcode says when running the app:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/cjm/AndroidStudioProjects/GlobeMultiplatform/androidApp/build.gradle.kts' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Actually unfold is only needed in Xcode, in AS you **Build Output** should contain al the information, it should be under `PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Build\...` line

Comment: This is all that it tells me...                                                                                                                  The following build commands failed:
 PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Build\ shared /Users/cjm/AndroidStudioProjects/GlobeMultiplatform/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-882AF45D8B8C4938AC461F4FBA0FE197.sh (in target 'shared' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Comment: I just run my sample app with a build error, and I can see full output. It may be a bug in your case, try restarting AS. If this doesn't help, you can run it in Xcode, the logs there for sure will be available.

Comment: I just added what Xcode says to the bottom of the question. What does this mean?

Comment: This [this answer](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43240#focus=Comments-27-4767506.0-0)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275254/14912754) might be helpful. Update Your kotlin version to `1.8.20`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that it tries to build your code with Java 1.8, you need a Java > 11 version.

I'd look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos) or other guidelines to make sure the proper JDK version is used