# java --version command on mac always shows latest version I have installed

Tags: java, homebrew, java-home

I have a new m1 mac.

I installed a few versions of the jdk (just following this tweet as an example)

So I did,

`brew tap mdogan/zulu`

`brew install --cask zulu-jdk17 zulu-jdk16 zulu-jdk11 zulu-jdk8`

Now I set my JAVA_HOME to point to jdk11 (most of my projects require jdk11), but when I run `java --version` it reports the info for 17.

And then if I run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v"11"` in my terminal, it'll say `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home`, but when I run `java --version` again it'll report 17.

How do I get `java --version` to report 11 so it's inline with my JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Your shell doesn't care about `JAVA_HOME`, only about `PATH`

Comment: Try `which java` in the command line, that'll show you what's actually being invoked.  It's probably a symlink to somewhere else, so you may need to change that.

Comment: `which java` shows `/usr/bin/java`. Pardon my ignorance while I read up what a sym link is.

Comment: Check this answer given for similar problem
It worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/12133296