# Changing MacOS java version, Eclipse OpenJ9

Tags: java, macos, version, openj9

I am using MacOS BigSur, trying to change java version to v1.8
I have followed the instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos) but no results.

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V` commands outputs:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But `java --version` command returns:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build openj9-0.26.0, JRE 11 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210421_957 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - b4cc246d9
OMR      - 162e6f729
JCL      - 7796c80419 based on jdk-11.0.11+9)
```

When I removed java completely from the OS following [these instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html) I would still get the same `java --version` output, but running `/usr/libexec/java_home`
would return

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

.zshrc file has JAVA_HOME set to `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_265`

Where can I find this java that is currently referenced with the java command, or where can I change that reference on the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very easy way of managing JDK installations almost automatically using something like [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io). I suggest you have a look at this, as it would greatly simplify the process of managing whatever is that you need to manage. Note that the solution work for both MacOS and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use SDKMAN and uninstall the current java version in order to get rid of this part in java -version command:

```
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build openj9-0.26.0, JRE 11 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210421_957 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - b4cc246d9
OMR      - 162e6f729
JCL      - 7796c80419 based on jdk-11.0.11+9)
```

After that I used brew to install java, set JAVA_HOME and after that gradle build was working fine.