# System checker fails on MacOS Big Sur with "Java is not reachable"

Tags: cytoscape

I'm having trouble running Cytoscape 3.9.1 on MacOS Big Sur. The system checker fails with the following:

```
############# Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Mac ##############
Target Cytoscape version: 3.9.0
Your shell is bash
Compatible OS version found: 11.6
 - Pass: OS Version = 11.6.1
 - Pass: Following Oracle JDK found:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk
Fail: Java is not reachable.
Try re-installing Java 11.
```

I have Java 11 installed at the location shown in the output, and it seems fine:

```
$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Permissions look right (these are the same all the way up the directory hierarchy):

```
$ ls -lh /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
total 6672
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jaotc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jarsigner
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 javac
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 javadoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 javap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jcmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jconsole
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jdb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jdeprscan
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jdeps
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jhsdb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jimage
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jinfo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jjs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jlink
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jmap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jmod
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jps
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jrunscript
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jshell
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jstack
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jstat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 jstatd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 keytool
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 pack200
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 rmic
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 rmid
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 rmiregistry
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   101K Oct  6  2019 serialver
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   110K Oct  6  2019 unpack200
```

I also have several more up-to-date Java versions installed (I'm not sure if these are causing the issue):

```
$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk-10.0.2.jdk      jdk-12.0.2.jdk      jdk-14.0.1.jdk      jdk1.8.0_181.jdk
jdk-11.0.5.jdk      jdk-13.0.2.jdk      jdk-17.0.1.jdk
```

The default is JDK17:

```
$ java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If I invoke `cytoscape.sh` directly from the command line, it appears to be trying to run under Java 8:

```
$ ./cytoscape.sh 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/cytoscape/launcher/internal/Launcher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cytoscape 3.9.1 will not run on JDK 17.  You need to set your JAVA_HOME to point to your JDK 11 installation and things *should* work.

Comment: Thanks: that works, though the only way I can find to do that is to run `export JAVA_HOME=...; ./cytoscape.sh` from the terminal. It's a little inconvenient but workable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Java. So I'm including my answer here if anyone else has the same issue as me.
First I went here to find out "[How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos)"

From there you should be able to find out the Java version you want to use. Then set your JAVA_HOME variable

Using bash or zsh you can set your JAVA_HOME environment variable like so:

*Bash Example*

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.7)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

*or in Zsh*

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.7)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Restart terminal after this.

You can check your shell profile and see that this line has now been added to the end of the profile:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can also check that java is mapped to the desired Java version by default now:

```
java -version
```

Running the System Checker Script on Mac should now recognize Java is installed correctly

```
./mac.sh
```

Cytoscape should now run by clicking on the `cytoscape.sh` script

Comment: That's fine, as long as you want your default JVM to be Java 11. I need it to be Java 17 (or later) for other reasons.