# gradle wrapper reports x86-64 architecture instead of arm-v8 architecture on Mac m1

Tags: java, gradle, apple-m1, openjdk-17

Hello when working from a Mac m1, Gradle wrapper task reports incorrect architecture compared to gradle :

Here is the result of `./gradlew clean` :

```
operating system 'Mac OS X'
architecture 'x86-64'
osx
x86_64
x86_64
```

Here is the result of `gradle clean` :

```
operating system 'Mac OS X'
architecture 'arm-v8'
osx
aarch_64
aarch64
```

Does someone have an explanation for that.

Additional information : output of `gradle --version`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.1 (Homebrew 18.0.1+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.2.1 aarch64
```

here is the content of my build.gradle to display architecture :

```
println org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem;
println org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform.currentArchitecture;
println osdetector.os
println osdetector.arch
println System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

I generated the Gradle wrapper from my Mac m1 using `gradle wrapper`.

Comment: Do you have multiple JVMs installed on your machine; an x86 one and a native ARM one? Perhaps one command is picking up one JVM, and the other command the other. What does `./gradlew --version` print?

Comment: Indeed this is it, I have mutliple JVMs installed and the default one is a x86-64 running with rosetta. Did change it to the arm-v8 version installed by homebrew and it solves my issue. Thanks a lot Jesper

Comment: @Antonin Please written, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question. Doing so marks the page as resolved, and more easily helps posterity. Include [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29#Rosetta_2) to Wikipedia.

Comment: Alright @BasilBourque  wanted to do so anyways, not found the time to yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Jesper's comment here is a solution to that issue.

## TL;DR

List the JVMs on your system and verify that you have at lease one (arm64) JVM.

```
➜  ~ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    18.0.1.1 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 18.0.1.1" /Users/you/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home
    18.0.1.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 18.0.1.1" /Users/you/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1-1/Contents/Home
    18.0.1 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 18.0.1" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
/Users/you/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home
```

[Setup your JAVA_HOME environment variable to an arm64 JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos) :

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -a arm64`
```

## What happened in my case :

This is caused by multiple JVMs installed on the system. Some JVMs are compiled for arm64 and run natively, and some other are compiled for x86_64 and run in a ["translator" (rosetta)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29).

- Oracle x86_64 JDK installed by intelliJ IDEA.
- OpenJDK arm64 installed by Homebrew as a dependency of gradle.

Did not follow the "Caveat" of openJDK :

```
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

So the homebrew installed gradle was using the homebrew installed JVM. But gradlew scripts were using the default system JVM (the Oracle x86_64 JVM).