# Setting JAVA_HOME in zshrc on M1 Mac?

Tags: java, macos, zsh, java-home

When I use

`/usr/libexec/java_home`

I get

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home`

but I want to be getting

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home`

I've changed my .zshrc file a number of times and it seems to always revert to the default of temurin 17.

My application will not run android pointing to temurin 17 and it should be selecting zulu 11 jdk.

Comment: Do you happen to be using IntelliJ or Android Studio? I believe you can change the JVM to whichever you please for certain projects in Preferences.

Comment: A good tool to easily switch between java versions on the fly is [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/)

Comment: Did you check [this](https://medium.com/notes-for-geeks/java-home-and-java-home-on-macos-f246cab643bd) page? It shows how to run a Java process with a specific JAVA_HOME setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you should do after changing `.zshrc` file is to execute:

`source ~/.zshrc` in order for the changes in your `.zshrc` to be activated

---

But I would suggest when working with multiple java version, to setup alias and be able to easily change versions on-demand.

You can find a guide for this on this Stackoverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754792/2352196